# Drawing a gradient in ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

**Task description:**

Write a program as short as possible to draw a radial gradient in ASCII art. The size of the output grid is predefined. The center point and the characters to be used for the gradient are provided as input to the program.

The gradient will be 70×25 character cells in size with the following specifications

- The upper-left corner of the grid has the coordinates (0, 0).
- The gradient, consisting of the characters provided, is mapped into 35 *length units*. A length unit is one character tall and two characters wide (since `monospaced fonts` usually have characters twice as high as they are wide).
- Within those 35 LU the current distance from the center point is multiplied by <sup>number of gradient characters</sup>/<sub>35</sub> to get the index of the character to draw at that point. Fractional numbers for the index are rounded towards zero here. The length units are to be left as a real number. (Of course, if the results are the same, the implementation doesn't matter.)
- Beyond those 35 LU only the last gradient character appears. However, since the last gradient »band« already starts *within* the 35 LU, the last character starts appearing short of 35 LU already.

**Input:**

The input is given on standard input and consists of three lines, each terminated by a line break:

- The *x* coordinate of the gradient center point
- The *y* coordinate of the gradient center point
- The characters to use for drawing the gradient. Those may include spaces.

**Output:**

Output is the gradient as defined by the rules above on standard output. The standard error stream is ignored. Each line of the gradient is terminated by a line break. No other characters except those defined by the input may occur.

**Sample input 1:**

```
58
14
 .:;+=xX$&
```

**Sample output 1:**

```
&&$$$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxx===========++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
&$$$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxx=========+++++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;+
$$$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx=========+++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
$$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx========++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx========+++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::;;;;;
$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx=======+++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::;
$$$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxxx=======+++++++++;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======++++++++;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx========+++++++;;;;;;;;::::::::::...............::::
$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;;:::::::::...................::
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======++++++++;;;;;;;::::::::.......................
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;::::::::.........       ........
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;:::::::........           ......
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;:::::::.......             .....
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;:::::::.......             .....
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;:::::::.......             .....
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;:::::::........           ......
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;::::::::.........       ........
$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======++++++++;;;;;;;::::::::.......................
$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======+++++++;;;;;;;;:::::::::...................::
$$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxx========+++++++;;;;;;;;::::::::::...............::::
$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxx=======++++++++;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$$XXXXXXXxxxxxxxx=======+++++++++;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx=======+++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::;
$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx========+++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::;;;;;
```

**Sample input 2:**

```
0
0
X.X.X.X
```

**Sample output 2:**

```
XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
..................XXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX
................XXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXX
...............XXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXX
............XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXX
.........XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX................XXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX..................XXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
...........................XXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
........................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
......................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
..................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX......................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**Sample input 3:**

```
70
25
.:+#
```

**Sample output 3:**

```
######################################################++++++++++++++++
#################################################+++++++++++++++++++++
#############################################+++++++++++++++++++++++++
##########################################++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#######################################+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
####################################++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
##################################++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
################################++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
##############################++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++::::::::
#############################+++++++++++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::
###########################+++++++++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::
##########################++++++++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::::
#########################++++++++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::::::::
########################+++++++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::::::::::
#######################++++++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
######################++++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#####################+++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
####################+++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::::::::.......
####################++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::::::..........
###################+++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::::............
###################++++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::::..............
###################+++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::::...............
##################++++++++++++++++++::::::::::::::::::................
##################++++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::.................
##################++++++++++++++++++:::::::::::::::::.................
```

**Sample input 4**

```
59
1
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789<>|,.-#+!$%&/()=?*'_:;
```

**Sample output 4**

```
!+#-,|><87654210ZYWVUTRQPONLKJIHFEDCBzyxwutsrqonmlkjhgfedcbbbcdefghjkl
!+#-,|><87654210ZYWVUTRQPONLKJIHFEDCAzyxwutsrqonmljihgfdcba abcdfghijl
!+#-,|><87654210ZYWVUTRQPONLKJIHFEDCBzyxwutsrqonmlkjhgfedcbbbcdefghjkl
!+#-,|><97654310ZYXVUTSQPONMKJIHGEDCBAyxwvutrqponmkjihgffeedeeffghijkm
$+#-.|><98654320ZYXWUTSRQONMLKIHGFEDBAzyxwutsrqponmlkjihhggggghhijklmn
$!#-.,|<987643210YXWVUSRQPONLKJIHGEDCBAzywvutsrqponmllkjjjiiijjjkllmno
$!+#.,|><87654210ZYXVUTSRQONMLKJHGFEDCBAzywvutsrrqponnmmlllllllmmnnopq
%!+#-.|><987543210YXWVUTRQPONMLJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrrqppooonnnnnoooppqrr
%$!+-.,|><87654310ZYXWVTSRQPONMLJIHGFEDCBAzyxxwvuttssrrqqqqqqqqqrrsstt
&%!+#-.,><987643210ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyyxwvvuutttssssssstttuuvv
&%$!+#.,|><986543210ZYWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDDCBAzzyyxwwwvvvuuuuuvvvwwwxy
/&%$!#-.,|><976543210ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKKJIHGFEEDCBBAAzzyyyxxxxxxxxxyyyzzA
(/&%!+#-.,|><876543210ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJJIHGGFEEDCCBBBAAAzzzzzzzAAABBBC
)(/%$!+#-.,|><876543210ZYXWVUTSRQPPONMLKKJIIHGGFFEEDDDCCCCCCCCCCCDDDEE
=)(&%$!+#-.,|><986543210ZYYXWVUTSRQPPONMMLKKJIIHHGGGFFFEEEEEEEEEFFFGGG
?=)(&%$!+#-.,|><9876543210ZYXWVVUTSRRQPOONMMLLKJJJIIIHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIJ
*?=)(/%$!+#-.,|><98765432210ZYXWWVUTSSRQQPOONNMMLLLKKKJJJJJJJJJJJKKKLL
'*?=)(/&%$!+#-.,|><98765432110ZYXXWVUUTSSRRQPPOOONNNMMMMMLLLLLMMMMMNNN
_'*?=)(/&%$!+#-.,|><988765432210ZYYXWWVUUTTSSRRQQQPPPOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPQ
:_'*?=)(/&%$!+##-.,|><9877654332100ZYYXXWVVUUTTTSSSRRRRQQQQQQQQQRRRRSS
;;:_'*?=)(/&%$!+#-.,,|><98876554322100ZZYYXXWWVVVUUUTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUU
;;;:_'*?=)(/&&%$!+#-.,,|><9987665443321100ZZYYYXXXWWWWVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWX
;;;;;:_'*?=)(/&%$$!+#-..,|>><9887665544322211000ZZZYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZ
;;;;;;:_'*??=)(/&%%$!+##-.,,|><<99877665544333222111100000000000001111
;;;;;;;;:_'*?==)(/&&%$!++#--.,,|>><<9887766655544433333322222223333334
```

A week has passed. It is time to unveil the solution lengths from our university's contest:

> 167 – Python
>   189 – Haskell
>   203 – C
>   210 – VB.NET
>   219 – C

And our own solutions:

> 91 – GolfScript
>   125 – [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/430/drawing-a-gradient-in-ascii-art/777#777)
>   157 – [PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/430/drawing-a-gradient-in-ascii-art/770#770)

Comment: I was thinking it would be cool to have a tag for ascii-art questions too

Comment: I'm either having trouble with the concept of LU or you sample outputs are incorrect. From what I understood in each band there should be an even number of characters, yet in your samples this isn't true. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: @Juan: What exactly do you mean? I suck at explaining and did so last year already, to be honest. The last band extends to the rest of the image. Otherwise, the second example makes it most clear, I think. Since the 35 LU are 70 characters wide, each band (of which there are 7) is 10 characters wide in the top line. Along the left edge each band is 5 characters tall (but only the first 5 bands fit into the height of the grid).

Comment: @Joey What I mean is, in a given line, the width of a band should be even, since a band would be composed by n LU (each 2 characters wide). Thus we have 2*n characters per band per line. Is this right?

Comment: @Juan: Hm, the rounding should be applied to the character index, not the length units. I'll try rephrasing in a way that's less ambiguous. Another point: The entire grid is to be taken as a character grid, not a SLU (square length unit :-)) grid. The LU thing is just to help making the difference between horizontal and vertical distances clearer. Doesn't seem to work very well. Originally I had an explicit formula in there, it was removed since it was deemed too easy.

Comment: If anyone still has doubts, coordinates are on characters, distances are on LUs.

Comment: @ninja: I welcome suggestions for the description. As noted, I failed to accurately define the task parameters the first time already ;-)

Comment: @Joey: I'm not a native English speaker, so I'll pass on trying to improve your description. How's that for an excuse? ;-P

Comment: @ninjalj: Me neither :-)

Comment: @Joey: Where are the C answers?

Comment: @PatrickvL: http://hypftier.de/dump/codegolf2010 I only posted the lengths, since some people asked, though.

Comment: @Joey: You might want to update your final chart ;-)

Comment: @PatrickvL: No, I don't. As mentioned, those were only the results of our contest a year ago since somebody asked. The submissions here are listed below the question for easy viewing, as usual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9, <del>116 114 108</del> 101 characters

```
x,y,z=*$<;25.times{|r|70.times{|c|$><<z[[(c-x.to_i+2.i*(r-y.to_i)).abs/70.0*k=z=~/$/,k-1].min]};puts}
```

Answer (score 31):

## Brainfuck - 1286

This is one of my favorite creations yet. Includes a working (for some definitions of working) square root function.

```
>,>,<<<<<<<+>,[<+[<+>-],]<-[>>[>]>>>+<<<<[<]<-]>>[<+<+<+>>>-]<<<[>>>+<
<<-]>[>]>>>>>>>+++++[<+++++>-]<[>>+++++++[<++++++++++>-]<[>>+++++++[<+
+++++++++>-]<<[>->+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<<<[>>>>->+<<<<<-]>>>>>[<<<<<+>>>>>
-]<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>>+++++++[<<++++++++++>>-]>[-]>[-]+>[-]<<<<[>+>+<<-
]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>-
>]<+<<-]>[-]>[-]<<<[-]<[-<+[+>+<]>+[<+>-]]++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<
<<<<]>[-]>[-]>[<<<+>>>-]<+++++[<+++++>-]<<<<[>>>->+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>
>-]<<<<<[>>>>->+<<<<<-]>>>>>[<<<<<+>>>>>-]<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]>>+++++[<<+
++++>>-]>[-]>[-]+>[-]<<<<[>+>+<<-]>[<+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>>[>-]>[<<<<->>[-
]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<->>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>[-]>[-]<<<[-]<[-<+[+>+<]>+[<
+>-]]<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<[<+>>+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<[-]<[<<+>>-]<
[>+>+<<-]>[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<[<+>>+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<[-]<[<<+>>-]<<>+>>+<<<[
[>>+>>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]>[-]>[-]+>[-]<<<<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<[>
>>+<<<-]>>>[>-]>[<<<<+>>[-]>>->]<+<<[>-[>-]>[<<<<+>>[-]+>>->]<+<<-]>[-
]>[-]<<+<<[>>-<[-]<-<<[-]>>]>>[-<<<[>+>+<<-]+>[<+>>+<-]>+>]<<<<]>[<+>-
]<-<<<<<[<+>->>>>>>+<<<<<<]<[>+<-]>>>>>>[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<[<+>>+<-]>[<+>
-]>-]<+++++++<[-]>[<+++++>-]<<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>[-]>[
<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<<<[-<[>>+<<-]>[<+>-]<]<.>>>[[<<+>>-]
>]>>>>>-]++++++++++.[-]<-]
```

Output is a bit off due to rounding errors, but still recognizable. Floating point is beyond my current skill level. Unfortunately this will only work with 16 bit cells, which means it is going to be dog slow.

Output 1:

```
&$$$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx========++++++++++++++++++++++;;;++++++++++
$$$$$$$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx========++++++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
$$$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx========++++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
$$$$$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx======++++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:::;;;;;;;;;;
$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx========++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::;;
$$$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx======++++++++++;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++++;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;;;::::::::::::::::...::::::::::
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx========++++++++;;;;;;::::::::::::...............::::
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;;;::::::::::...................::
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::::..........   ..........
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::........           ......
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::......               ....
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::......               ....
$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::......                   ..
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::......               ....
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::......               ....
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::........           ......
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;::::::::::..........   ..........
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;;;::::::::::...................::
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx========++++++++;;;;;;::::::::::::...............::::
$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx======++++++++;;;;;;;;::::::::::::::::...::::::::::
$$$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxx======++++++++++;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$$XXXXXXxxxxxxxxxx======++++++++++;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::::::::
$$$$$XXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx========++++++++++;;;;;;;;;;:::::::::::::::::::;;
```

Output 2:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
XX................XXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
..................XXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
................XXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
..............XXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXX
..........XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXX
..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX................XXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX..................XXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XX..........................XXXXXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
..........................XXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
......................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
..................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
..............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX....................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX......................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I'm torn between considering this awful and awesome :D. I guess an accurate square root could be done only with a lookup table, or with much more code

Comment: Lookup wouldn't help. I can calculate the integer below the square root just fine. You need a new data representation to handle floating point, and I'm just not ready to make that jump.

Answer (score 12):

### Python - 141 chars

```
x=input();y=input();z=raw_input();w=len(z)
for i in range(-y,25-y):print"".join(z[min(w-1,int((i*i*4+j*j)**.5*w/70))]for j in range(-x,70-x))
```

Answer (score 8):

### Delphi, 200 (and 185)

Since I like ascii-art here a Delphi version of this code golf:

```
uses Math;var G:string;X,Y,l,i,j:Int16;begin ReadLn(X,Y);ReadLn(G);l:=Length(G);for j:=-y to 24-y do for i:=-x to 70-x do if i=70-x then WriteLn else Write(g[Min(l,1+Trunc(l*sqrt(i*i/4+j*j)/35))])end.
```

Not very impressive character-wise, as I had to use the Math unit to link in the Min() function. Also, ReadLn() somehow doesn't read integers and strings in one call, so that's quite expensive too. The newline needs a lot of characters too. Also, Delphi needs quite a lot of whitespace around it's keywords. Not very proud of this one.

Anyway, the output of sample 4 gives me :

```
!+#-,|><87654210ZYWVUTRQPONLKJIHFEDCBzyxwutsrqonmlkjhgfedcbbbcdefghjkl
!+#-,|><87654210ZYWVUTRQPONLKJIHFEDCAzyxwutsrqonmljihgfdcba abcdfghijl
!+#-,|><87654210ZYWVUTRQPONLKJIHFEDCBzyxwutsrqonmlkjhgfedcbbbcdefghjkl
!+#-,|><97654310ZYXVUTSQPONMKJIHGEDCBAyxwvutrqponmkjihgffeedeeffghijkm
$+#-.|><98654320ZYXWUTSRQONMLKIHGFEDBAzyxwutsrqponmlkjihhggggghhijklmn
$!#-.,|<987643210YXWVUSRQPONLKJIHGEDCBAzywvutsrqponmllkjjjiiijjjkllmno
$!+#.,|><87654210ZYXVUTSRQONMLKJHGFEDCBAzywvutsrrqponnmmlllllllmmnnopq
%!+#-.|><987543210YXWVUTRQPONMLJIHGFEDCBAzyxwvutsrrqppooonnnnnoooppqrr
%$!+-.,|><87654310ZYXWVTSRQPONMLJIHGFEDCBAzyxxwvuttssrrqqqqqqqqqrrsstt
&%!+#-.,><987643210ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAzyyxwvvuutttssssssstttuuvv
&%$!+#.,|><986543210ZYWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDDCBAzzyyxwwwvvvuuuuuvvvwwwxy
/&%$!#-.,|><976543210ZYXVUTSRQPONMLKKJIHGFEEDCBBAAzzyyyxxxxxxxxxyyyzzA
(/&%!+#-.,|><876543210ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJJIHGGFEEDCCBBBAAAzzzzzzzAAABBBC
)(/%$!+#-.,|><876543210ZYXWVUTSRQPPONMLKKJIIHGGFFEEDDDCCCCCCCCCCCDDDEE
=)(&%$!+#-.,|><986543210ZYYXWVUTSRQPPONMMLKKJIIHHGGGFFFEEEEEEEEEFFFGGG
?=)(&%$!+#-.,|><9876543210ZYXWVVUTSRRQPOONMMLLKJJJIIIHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIJ
*?=)(/%$!+#-.,|><98765432210ZYXWWVUTSSRQQPOONNMMLLLKKKJJJJJJJJJJJKKKLL
'*?=)(/&%$!+#-.,|><98765432110ZYXXWVUUTSSRRQPPOOONNNMMMMMLLLLLMMMMMNNN
_'*?=)(/&%$!+#-.,|><988765432210ZYYXWWVUUTTSSRRQQQPPPOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPQ
:_'*?=)(/&%$!+##-.,|><9877654332100ZYYXXWVVUUTTTSSSRRRRQQQQQQQQQRRRRSS
;;:_'*?=)(/&%$!+#-.,,|><98876554322100ZZYYXXWWVVVUUUTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUU
;;;:_'*?=)(/&&%$!+#-.,,|><9987665443321100ZZYYYXXXWWWWVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWX
;;;;;:_'*?=)(/&%$$!+#-..,|>><9887665544322211000ZZZYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZ
;;;;;;:_'*??=)(/&%%$!+##-.,,|><<99877665544333222111100000000000001111
;;;;;;;;:_'*?==)(/&&%$!++#--.,,|>><<9887766655544433333322222223333334
```

If you would accept indented output, this version is a bit shorter by changing the newline into an indent that leads to a 80-character wrap (simulating a newline on standard 80x25 consoles) :

```
uses Math;var G:string;X,Y,l,i,j:Int16;begin ReadLn(X,Y);ReadLn(G);l:=Length(G);for j:=-y to 24-y do for i:=-x to 70-x do Write(g[Min(l,1+Trunc(l*sqrt(i*i/4+j*j)/35))]:11*Ord(i=-x))end.
```

(this saves 15 characters, for a total of 185 characters).
It's output for "0 0 X.X.X.X" is :

```
          XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX
          ..................XXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX
          ................XXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXX
          ...............XXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXX
          ............XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXX..........XXXXXXXXXXXX
          .........XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXX...........XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX................XXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXX..................XXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          ...........................XXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          ........................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          ......................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          ..................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          .............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...............XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          XXXXXXXXXXXXXX......................XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

(Can you see the indent?! ;-) )

Answer (score 8):

### APL (74)

```
{L←⍴⊃C Y X⎕IO←⍞⎕⎕0⋄⎕←{C[⊃⌊L⌊35÷⍨L×.5*⍨+/2*⍨1 2÷⍨⍵-Y X]}¨⍳⍵}25 70
```

The reason it's wrapped in a function is that the modification to `⎕IO` doesn't apply to the rest of the system.

Explanation:

- `L←⍴⊃C Y X⎕IO←⍞⎕⎕0`: Set `⎕IO` to `0` (making arrays 0-based instead of 1-based), set X to `⎕` (first line read), set Y to `⎕` (second line read), set C to `⍞` (third line read, with no formatting), and set L to the length (`⍴`) of `C`.
- `25 70`: the dimensions of the matrix.
- `¨⍳⍵`: for each element in the matrix where each element is its own coordinates...
- `⍵-Y X`: difference between the current point and the center point
- `1 2÷⍨`: divide the X coordinate by 2 (because a char is half as wide as it is tall)
- `.5*⍨+/2*⍨`: take the square root of the sum of the squares
- `35÷⍨`: divide by 35
- `⌊L⌊`: take the minimum of the amount of characters and the current value and round it down
- `,/`: The values are still wrapped in a list (of only one element), and this will create spacing in the output, so 'free' the values from their lists.
- `C[`...`]`: use the value we found as an index into the character list
- `⎕←`: we now have a matrix where each element (x,y) is the character for (x,y), so output the matrix.

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 5.10, 103 chars

```
$x=<>;$y=<>;@C=<>=~/./g;for$j(-$y..24-$y){print+(map$C[@C/35*sqrt$_**2/4+$j**2]//$C[-1],-$x..69-$x),$/}
```

Comment: Thanks to @J B for the nice trick at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/678/decipher-a-vigenere-ciphertext/709#709

Comment: Also thanks to @gnibbler for his "substraction precalculated in range" trick.

Comment: You got an empty line before the output. So currently this is counted as invalid.

Comment: @Joey: fixed ...

Comment: Still fails a test case of mine, here, though. I added it to the question (Sample 4). Somehow the zeroes in the output get replaced by a semicolon.

Comment: @Joey: should work now, though I don't have a Perl 5.10 handy to test.

Comment: Tested with Perl 5.12 here and works apart from a stray X where an Y should be. Chosen to ignore now for the sake of my sanity. (We actually had a bunch of test cases for all tasks we used in the contest so we could automatically test submissions for passing).

Comment: @Joey: that can be fixed at the cost of 2 chars by rearranging operations like this: `sqrt($_**2/4+$j**2)*@C/35`

Comment: Well, that doesn't change the ranking ;-)

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 120 chars

```
$x,$y=<>,<>;@C=split'',<>;for$j(0..24){print+(map$C[($c=$#C/35*sqrt(($x/2-$_/2)**2+($y-$j)**2))<$#C?$c:$#C-1],0..69),$/}
```

Comment: fails on the first and third examples. `abs` is there for a reason.

Comment: Squaring removes the sign anyway, I don't see how abs would change anything

Comment: D'oh! You're completely right. What's failing on my system is  `$x,$y=<>,<>;`.

Answer (score 4):

### Windows PowerShell, 157

Nothing noteworthy. Beaten to death already:

```
$x,$y,$c=@($input)
$l=$c.Length
$c+=(""+$c[-1])*90
0..24|%{$r=$_
-join(0..69|%{$c[[math]::truncate([math]::sqrt(($x-$_)*($x-$_)+4*($y-$r)*($y-$r))*$l/70)]})}
```

Answer (score 2):

### C, 176

Here a translation of my Delphi solution to C, saving 24 characters :

```
X,Y,l,i,j,t;char G[99];main(){scanf("%d\n%d\n",&X,&Y);gets(G);l=strlen(G);for(j=-Y;j<25-Y;j++)for(i=-X-1;i<70-X;)t=floor(l*sqrt(i*i++/4+j*j)/35),putchar(!i+X?10:G[t<l?t:l-1]);}
```

You can test this code here : http://www.ideone.com/oTvHt

Comment: You can put the declaration of the int variables in the argument list of `main()` I guess and save a semicolon that way.

Comment: [171 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY1dC4IwGIXv@xUVFJvbSvsg9FW69C9MqgtZaRuvWm5dRf30VsbhwMOBh6NErZT3BUeuueEO1LXsx/khjk/QlLolkj6tKtuKTGfnYzt0yueSzwsK9cVZklPAzLoeL@3AVdcTk70LYMykq60ogA6Tzt4SdLoLhYTbww0nZKKZ3Edhkh9cinuXoIhOlLqswu5nYGDvvSM60IwtN8wEhi7XWwov78NROJKLfz6qwrK2XmDzBQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

#### Common Lisp, 173 characters

```
(let*((c(read))(v(read))(g(read-line))(l(length g)))(dotimes(y 25)(dotimes(x 70)(princ(elt g(min(floor(*(sqrt(+(expt(/(- c x)2)2)(expt(- v y)2)))l)35)(1- l)))))(princ #\
)))
```

The only real trick I use here is using

```
#\[actual newline]
```

as a newline character literal

Answer (score 1):

#### C# 311

Thought I'd make a long program to make the others feel better:

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){Func<string>r=Console.ReadLine;int x=int.Parse(r()),y=int.Parse(r());var c=r();for(int j=0;j<25;j++){for(int i=0;i<70;i++){var l=c.Length;Console.Write(c[(int)Math.Min(l*Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x-i)/2.0,2)+Math.Pow(Math.Abs(y-j),2))/35,l-1)]);}Console.Write("\n");}}}
```

Input is taken from the console, one line at a time (two lines for the coordinates and one for the gradient chars).

Thanks to [Joey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15/joey) for the tips.

Sample 1: http://ideone.com/X0jIZ

Sample 2: http://ideone.com/RvICt

Comment: @Joey Right. I fixed it and realized why trying this in C# was a pretty bad idea. It was fun though. :-)

Comment: @Joey you're right, neither the class nor the method need to be marked as *public*

Comment: @Joey if we use `int` instead of `float`, the expressions `x-i` and `y-j` become of type `int`. Due to this, the `int Math.Abs(int value) will be called instead of the float one, leading to some loss of precision. I've tried it and got som e rough edges: http://ideone.com/wQcMT

Comment: @Joey Right, Abs does not affect precision, but it returns an int, which, when divided by 2 will lose precision, as opposed to a float.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a modification that will work the way you want (costs two characters, but the `int`s will save more ;)). Oh, and `*.5` costs only one char.

Comment: @Joey the `using C` is a nice trick to keep in mind, but in this case it adds a bit to the char count. I also tried `using M=System.Math`, and it's the same.

Comment: @Joey yep, right about the `int`s. Saved 4 more chars.

Comment: You can put the declaration of `i` and `j` before the loops, too. Which saves two `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

#### scala 223 (204 without App-Wrapper)

```
object C extends App{
import math._
def r=readInt
val p=r
val q=r
val m=readLine
(1 to 70)map(x=>(0 to 25)map(y=>{
printf("%c[%d;%dH%s",27,y,x,m(({
val a=abs(p-x)
val b=abs(q-y)
sqrt(a*a+2*b*b)
}*(m.size-1)/74).toInt))}
))}
```

Having cols and rows (70, 25) set dynamically would allow for screenfilling gradients.