# Decipher a Vigenère ciphertext

Tags: code-golf, cipher

The [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) was a simple polyalphabetic cipher that basically applied one of several Caesar ciphers, according to a key. Basically the letters in the key indicate which shifted alphabet to use. To that end there was a simple tool, called the *Vigenère square:*

[image]

Here each row is a separate alphabet, starting with the corresponding letter of the key. The columns then are used to determine the ciphered letter. Decryption works in very much the same fashion, only vice-versa.

Suppose we want to encrypt the string `CODEGOLF`. We also need a key. In this case the key shall be `FOOBAR`. When the key is shorter than the plaintext we extend it by repetition, therefore the actual key we use is `FOOBARFO`. We now look up the first letter of the key, which is `F` to find the alphabet. It starts, perhaps unsurprisingly, with `F`. Now we find the column with the first letter of the plaintext and the resulting letter is `H`. For the second letter we have `O` as the key letter and the plain text letter, resulting in `C`. Continuing that way we finally get `HCRFGFQT`.

**Task**

Your task now is to decipher messages, given a key. However, since we have outgrown the 16th century and have computers we should at least support a slightly larger alphabet:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
```

The construction of the Vigenère square is still very much the same and the cipher still works in the same way. It's just a bit ... unwieldy to give here in full.

**Input**

Input is given on standard input as two separate lines of text, each terminated by a line break. The first line contains the key while the second contains the ciphertext.

**Output**

A single line, containing the deciphered message.

**Winning condition**

Since encryption is sometimes regarded as a weapon, the code should be short to facilitate easy smuggling. The shorter the better, as it reduces the likelihood of discovery.

**Sample input 1**

```
Key
miQ2eEO
```

**Sample output 1**

```
Message
```

**Sample input 2**

```
ThisIsAKey
CoqKuGRUw29BiDTQmOpJFpBzlMMLiPb8alGruFbu
```

**Sample output 2**

```
ThisWorksEquallyWellWithNumbers123894576
```

A week has passed. The currently shortest solution has been accepted. For those interested, in our contest we had the following submissions and lengths:

> 130 – Python
> 146 – Haskell
> 195 – C
> 197 – C
> 267 – VB.NET

And our own solutions that weren't ranked with the others:

> 108 – Ruby
> 139 – PowerShell

Comment: It seems that [this](/q/86986/41024) can be useful to print the Vigenère square.

Comment: Theoretically, using this cipher with a non-repeating key the same length as the message makes it completely and utterly unbreakable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Golfscript -- 48 chars

```
n%~.,@*\{\(123,97>91,65>+58,48>+:|?@|?\-|=}%\0<+
```

No tricks in this one!

Comment: +1 I went to bed thinking there must be a way to get this down to ~50, now I see it's possible but I probably would not have managed it any time soon

Answer (score 8):

### MS-DOS 16bit .COM file - 87 bytes

Base64 encoded binary ([following this link for a decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp))

```
v1cBi8/oQACJ/ovv6DkAi9msitAqF3MDgMI+gMJhgPp6dguA6jqA+lp2A4DqK80hO/d0IkM563TW69YsYXMIBCB9AgQrBBqqtAHNITwNdev+xLIKzSHD
```

Comment: Usually you write short source code yourself for golfing. While probably not impossible, I somehow doubt it with this.

Comment: @Joey: What, you've never hand encoded machine code instructions! Just what do they teach youngsters these days! ;-)

Comment: Skizz: I did. Not in Base64, though ;) (we had a class a few years ago where we had to write programs for a Siemens 80C167 in assembler – and in the exams also assemble them into machine code. I thought about digging out that knowledge for the Assembler Quine task, but we had no output facilities [at least, they varied]).

Comment: @Joey: The Base64 is just a convenience for the other users on this site, it's easy to decode and save as a binary file (the link in the answer has that option).

Comment: Aah, sorry. I thought you'd have given the length of the Base64. Well, Chris once included arbitrary characters into a solution and just gave a hexdump besides his answer. I did similar in Weather forecast.

Answer (score 8):

### APL (45)

```
∆[⍙⍳⍨¨⌽∘∆¨(⍴⍙←⍞)⍴1-⍨⍞⍳⍨∆←⎕D,⍨⎕A,⍨⎕UCS 96+⍳26]
```

Explanation:

- `∆←⎕D,⍨⎕A,⍨⎕UCS 96+⍳26`: generate the alphabet (numbers (`⎕D`) follow letters (`⎕A`) follow lowercase letters (`⎕UCS 96+⍳26`, the unicode values from 97 to 122).
- `1-⍨⍞⍳⍨∆`: read a line (the key), find the position of each character in the alphabet, and subtract one (arrays are one-based by default, so shifting by those values directly would shift the alphabet one too far).
- `(⍴⍙←⍞)⍴`: read another line (the message), and repeat the indices of the key so that it has the length of the message.
- `⌽∘∆¨`: rotate the alphabet by the indices belonging to the key
- `⍙⍳⍨¨`: look up each character in the message in the corresponding shifted alphabet
- `∆[`...`]`: look up the given indices in the normal alphabet, giving the corresponding characters.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby - <strike>132 127 122 109</strike> 100 characters

```
a,b=*$<
c=*?a..?z,*?A..?Z,*?0..?9
(b.size-1).times{|i|$><<c[c.index(b[i])-c.index(a[i%(a.size-1)])]}
```

Comment: Use `*$<` instead of `$<.to_a` and inline the lambda to save another few bytes. – [Ventero](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84/ventero) 5 mins ago

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I pulled that lambda out to save characters and somehow missed that it actually cost more.

Answer (score 5):

### Python - 122 chars

```
from string import*
L=letters+digits
R=raw_input
K,T=R(),R()
F=L.find
print"".join(L[F(i)-F(j)]for i,j in zip(T,K*len(T)))
```

Answer (score 5):

### J, 65 characters

```
v=:4 : 'a{~x(62|[:-/"1 a i.[,.#@[$])y[a=.a.{~62{.;97 65 48+/i.26'
```

Doesn't completely meet the spec since it's defined as a verb rather than taking input, but I'm posting it anyway with the intention of fiddling with it at a later date.

Usage:

```
   'miQ2eEO' v 'Key'
Message
   'CoqKuGRUw29BiDTQmOpJFpBzlMMLiPb8alGruFbu' v 'ThisIsAKey'
ThisWorksEquallyWellWithNumbers123894576
```

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 95 chars

Perl 5.010, run with `perl -E`:

```
%a=map{$_,$n++}@a=(a..z,A..Z,0..9);@k=<>=~/./g;
$_=<>;s/./$a[($a{$&}-$a{$k[$i++%@k]})%62]/ge;say
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python - <s>144</s> <s>143</s> <s>140</s> <s>136</s> 125 characters

Probably not the best, but hey:

```
from string import*
l=letters+digits
r=l.find
q=raw_input
k=q()
print"".join(l[(r(j)-r(k[i%len(k)]))%62]for i,j in enumerate(q()))
```

Comment: Huh, I was about to post something just like that. You can assign raw_input to a variable, 3 or so chars.

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - 65 chars

Still needs to be golfed more. For now, T is the text, K is the Key, L is the list of letters

```
n%):T,\~*:K;''26,{97+}%+.{32^}%10,{48+}%++:L;T{L\?K(L\?\:K;-L\=}%
```

Answer (score 3):

### K,<strike>81</strike> 61

```
k:0:0;,/$(m!+(`$'m)!+{(1_x),1#x}\m:,/.Q`a`A`n)[(#v)#k]?'v:0:0
```

.

```
k)k:0:0;,/$(m!+(`$'m)!+{(1_x),1#x}\m:,/.Q`a`A`n)[(#v)#k]?'v:0:0
ThisIsAKey
CoqKuGRUw29BiDTQmOpJFpBzlMMLiPb8alGruFbu
"ThisWorksEquallyWellWithNumbers123894576"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 115 chars

```
$a=join'',@A=(a..z,A..Z,0..9);$_=<>;chop;@K=split//;$_=<>;s/./$A[(index($a,$&)-index($a,$K[$-[0]%@K]))%@A]/ge;print
```

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript - 92 characters

```
n%~\.,:l;{0\{1$+\)\}%\;}:&;26'a'*&26'A'*&+10'0'*&+\@.,,{.l%3$=4$?\2$=4$?\- 62%3$\>1<}%\;\;\;
```

Probably much longer than it needs to be. Still trying to get my head around GS.

Heres the "ungolfed" and commented version

```
n%~\.,:l;
{0\{1$+\)\}%\;}:&; # This would be sortof an equivalent for range applied to strings
26'a'*&26'A'*&+10'0'*&+\@., # This mess generates the dictionary string,
# l = len(key)
# 0 dictionary (letters + digits)
# 1 key
# 2 text
{
    # 3 index
    .   #+1 Duplicate the index

    # Find the index of the key letter
    l%  #+1 Indice modulo key
    3$  #+2 Duplicate the key
    =   #+1 Get the key letter
    4$? #+1 Search the letters index

    # Find the index of the text letter
    \   #+1 Get the index
    2$  #+2 Get the text
    =   #+1 Get the text letter
    4$? #+0 Search the letters index

    # 3 key index
    # 4 letter index

    \-   #+1 get the index of the new letter

    62% #+1 wrap the index around the dictionary

    3$ #+2 Get the dictionary

    \> #+1 remove the first part of the dict around the target letter

    1< #+1 remove everythin after 
}%
\;
\;
\;
```

Answer (score 2):

### VBA, 288

Doesn't quite beat the listed VB.NET score (but I'm getting close):

```
Sub h(k,s)
v=Chr(0)
Z=Split(StrConv("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",64),v)
a=Split(StrConv(s,64),v):b=Split(StrConv(k,64),v)
For l=0 To Len(s)-1
j=l Mod Len(k)
g=0
For i=0 To 62:g=g+i*((Z(i)=b(j))-(Z(i)=a(l))):Next
x=x &Z(IIf(g<0,g+62,g))
Next
s=x
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```
Sub test()
k = "ThisIsAKey"
s = "CoqKuGRUw29BiDTQmOpJFpBzlMMLiPb8alGruFbu"
h k, s
MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Thanks to [Joey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15/joey) for the tip!

Comment: `g=g+IIf(Z(i)=c,i,0)-IIf(Z(i)=d,i,0)` would be one candidate I can spot. As well as trying out whether LF line endings are understood by VBA. At least one space in `x=x & Z(g)` could be left out too, I guess.

Comment: Another way of writing the line: `g=g+i*((Z(i)=d)-(Z(i)=c))
` (because `True` is −1 in VB). Could be that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Joey. I'll look for any other improvements and add that in.

Answer (score 2):

**C,186**

A bit late but .. (lines broken to avoid horizontal scrollbar).

```
char a[99],*s,*t;k,j;main(int m,char**v)
{for(;j<26;++j)a[j]=32|(a[j+26]=65+j),
a[52+j]=48+j;while(*v[2])
putchar(a[s=strchr(a,v[1][k++%strlen(v[1])])
,t=strchr(a,*v[2]++),s>t?t-s+62:t-s]);}
```

Nonbroken lines

```
char a[99],*s,*t;k,j;main(int m,char**v){for(;j<26;++j)a[j]=32|(a[j+26]=65+j),a[52+j]=48+j;while(*v[2])putchar(a[s=strchr(a,v[1][k++%strlen(v[1])]),t=strchr(a,*v[2]++),s>t?t-s+62:t-s]);}
```

A discussion about the process of golfing this code can be found here:
http://prob-slv.blogspot.com/2013/04/code-golf.html

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript 248

```
var v= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
function d(k,c){var a,b,o,x
a=k.charAt(0)
x=v.indexOf(a)
b=v.substr(x)+v.substring(0,x)
o= v.charAt(b.indexOf(c.charAt(0)))
k=k.substr(1)+a
c=c.substr(1)
return (c)?o+d(k,c):o}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Uiua, 42 characters

```
A←⊂/⊂⊞+"aA"⇡26+@0⇡10
&p⊏-∩(⊗∶A)↯△,∶&sc&scA
```

-4 thanks to Unrelated String

Comment: You can get rid of the `◿⧻A` since negative indices wrap around anyways, and turn the leftmost `:A` into just an `A` on the far right, since being forced to take STDIN has the mild upside that your input doesn't have to start on the bottom of the stack.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell (169)

```
import List
main=do c<-y;t<-y;putStrLn$map((k!!).(`mod`62))$zipWith(-)(g t)(cycle$g c)
k=['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']++['0'..'9']
y=getLine
f(Just x)=x
g=map$f.(`elemIndex`k)
```

Answer (score 1):

## J: 91 characters

```
[:{&{.&t({&t"0&(({.t=.1|.^:(i.62)a.{~(97+i.26),(65+i.26),48+i.10)&i.)"0@:$~#)|:@(i."1.,"0)]
```

For example:

```
    g=:[:{&{.&t({&t"0&(({.t=.1|.^:(i.62)a.{~(97+i.26),(65+i.26),48+i.10)&i.)"0@:$~#)|:@(i."1.,"0)]
    'ThisIsAKey' g 'CoqKuGRUw29BiDTQmOpJFpBzlMMLiPb8alGruFbu'
ThisWorksEquallyWellWithNumbers123894576
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 156 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LasMwELz7K5ZA0Aq7ovTWBhdy6MkuodSn3lRnU@TIsoiUktj4212pSulp57EMM66VWi7DZ0eth1epDNDFk9k72FoLU5bBt9TgnxDf/UmZryIdXj7fAJQLVkUThCl@1iUyyfzARsbzHNk24o@E7yN@ZHzTiFHZGEiyF@1gvDJnqfUVKy4OWvpQgIte2qmVjlAVXUivEWuhzJ4uuwMqfvdPOp7XwqmR@Pp2Z9EfU715gd8BFZSwqui6yhJvIu/V2wO97P60E7mz9sHwYRA0PMg2ZHhtMFk8m5cf)

```scala
(K,T)=>{val L=('a'to'z')++('A'to'Z')++('0'to'9');T.zip(Stream.continually(K).flatten).map{case(i,j)=>L((L.indexOf(i)-L.indexOf(j)+L.size)%L.size)}.mkString}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLTsJAFN33K05IzMwEbIw7TTBh4aoYYuzK3dje1sHptGkHAxi@vd4yLbC753VfXaat7vv6a0uZx5s2DrT35PIOq6bBXwTkVMC32nVF3VYyecaHb40rF0inUk0FlucE8KstLHlPbcecFFrA1xBHoTCfM14F/CnUxZ6b0vjBLR6C@CQu2prpqR3ng/WsyjQ@mkbyeNJVnNXOG7fT1h5kouLCas44FYYAcaX5JGS6I0izwFZh@TJqwFrKdWxcTvtNIY3CPa6QnXOGllzpvxXurvUYP11G/IRXRAMXhfUTXn@W0GE24nTAlXl/pNfNxLXU7axn4ebV/OKhf8P9vHUyWFR06vt/)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  def transform(K: String, T: String): String = {
    val letters = ('a' to 'z') ++ ('A' to 'Z')
    val digits = '0' to '9'
    val L = letters ++ digits
    (T.zip(Stream.continually(K).flatten))
      .map { case (i, j) =>
        L((L.indexOf(i) - L.indexOf(j) + L.length) % L.length)
      }
      .mkString
  }

  val K = "Key"
  val T = "miQ2eEO"
  val result = transform(K, T)
  println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 136 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 17 bytes

```
LẎZƛ÷kr₀Ǔ:£~ḟǓ∇_ḟ¥i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9cyIsIiIsIkzhuo5axpvDt2ty4oKAx5M6wqN+4bifx5PiiIdf4bifwqVpIiwiIiwibWlRMmVFT1xuS2V5Il0=)

Bitstring:

```
0110000111010001100100100100100010010101101010000010110100010111011110111110110000101100000011001010100000111000011100111110110100111001
```

Takes message then key

### Explained

```
LẎZƛ÷kr₀Ǔ:£~ḟǓ∇_ḟ¥i­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
LẎ                   # ‎⁡Repeat the key to the length of the message
  Z                  # ‎⁢Zip each character in the message to the extended key
   ƛ                 # ‎⁣To each pair:
     kr₀Ǔ            # ‎⁤  Push the string a-zA-Z0-9
         :£          # ‎⁢⁡  and store a copy in the register
    ÷      ~ḟ        # ‎⁢⁢  Find the position of the key character, not popping the alphabet string
             Ǔ       # ‎⁢⁣  Rotate the alphabet string left that many times
    ÷         ∇_     # ‎⁢⁤  Put the message character at the top of the stack, followed by the rotated alphabet
                ḟ    # ‎⁣⁡  Find the index of the message character in that alphabet
                 ¥i  # ‎⁣⁢  And index into the original alphabet string
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).