# Find the nth decimal of pi

Tags: code-golf, math, pi

There are already [30 challenges dedicated to pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi) but not a single one asks you to find the nth decimal, so...

## Challenge

For any integer in the range of `0 <= n <= 10000` display the nth decimal of pi.

## Rules

- Decimals are every number after `3.`
- Your program may be a function, or a full program
- You must output the result in base 10
- You may get `n` from any suitable input method (stdin, input(), function parameters, ...), but not hardcoded
- You may use [1-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array%5Fsystem%5Fcross-reference%5Flist) if that's native to your language of choice
- You don't have to deal with invalid input (`n == -1`, `n == 'a'` or `n == 1.5`)
- Builtins are allowed, if they support up to **at least** 10k decimals
- Runtime doesn't matter, since this is about the shortest code and not the fastest code
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins

## Test cases

```
f(0)     == 1
f(1)     == 4 // for 1-indexed languages f(1) == 1
f(2)     == 1 // for 1-indexed languages f(2) == 4
f(3)     == 5
f(10)    == 8
f(100)   == 8
f(599)   == 2
f(760)   == 4
f(1000)  == 3
f(10000) == 5
```

For reference, [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/%7Ehuberty/math5337/groupe/digits.html) are the first 100k digits of pi.

Comment: Built-ins? e.g. `str(pi())[n+2]`

Comment: What about [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/calculate-%cf%80-with-quadratic-convergence)?

Comment: @primo Allowed. This is to find the shortest code in each language

Comment: @primo how it is possible to generate an infinite array with codes like `pi()` and then get the `n+2`th digit is beyond me.

Comment: @LeakyNun Related, but not a dupe imo.

Comment: @LeakyNun that's very nearly a valid answer in Sage.

Comment: The closest dupe targets IMO are [Computing truncated digit sums powers of pi](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48202/194) (overloads the parameter, or it would just be a finite difference applied to this challenge), [Transmit pi precisely](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47808/194) (adds an index and suppresses some printing), and [Pi window encryption](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32690/194).

Comment: May we use base 16?

Comment: @Adám no, the result must be output in base 10

Comment: @Suever ofcourse! That rule is just to point out that 10k is the minimum that your program should be able to handle

Comment: I suggest adding f(599) to the test cases, as it can be easy to get it wrong (you need about 3 decimals extra precision).

Comment: Also f(760) = 4, which begins the sequence 4[999999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_nines_in_pi)8, is easy to round incorrectly.

Comment: @aditsu & Anders, edited them in, thanks!

Comment: Can we use external files?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 No, sorry.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### 05AB1E, 3 bytes

```
žs¤
```

**Explained**

```
žs   # push pi to N digits
  ¤  # get last digit
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5zwqQ&input=MTAwMDE)

Uses 1-based indexing.
Supports up to 100k digits.

Comment: Pi to n digits doesn't round?

Comment: @busukxuan No. It used a predefined constant of pi to 100k digits and retrieves N of them.

Comment: @Emigna That is very handy. Good solution.

Comment: Short and Sharp, PCG at its best

Answer (score 18):

### Python 2, 66 bytes

```python
n=input()+9
x=p=5L**7
while~-p:x=p/2*x/p+10**n;p-=2
print`x/5`[-9]
```

Input is taken from stdin.

---

**Sample Usage**

```python
$ echo 10 | python pi-nth.py
8

$ echo 100 | python pi-nth.py
8

$ echo 1000 | python pi-nth.py
3

$ echo 10000 | python pi-nth.py
5
```

Comment: Be careful about using n in the algorithm... output for 599 should be 2, not 1. Also you may want to specify that you're using python 2.

Comment: @aditsu updated. Confirmed for all _n ≤ 1000_.

Comment: If you take `n` to be the input plus 9, you can avoid parens.

Comment: The first few digits generated by this algorithm are ‘3.141596535897932…’ which is missing a ‘2’ between places 5 and 6. Why? Because that’s when Python 2’s `` operator starts appending an `L` to the string.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg The `L` is present in the very first iteration - [demo](http://codepad.org/YWi4q3j1). True for both 32 and 64-bit versions of CPython.

Comment: @primo That is not what I get on 64-bit CPython (I tried 2.3.7, 2.4.6, 2.5.6, 2.6.9, 2.7.6, and 2.7.12), but I’ll accept that it works on 32-bit CPython.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg you're right, 64-bit on Linux did have an issue. Should now be correct.

Answer (score 11):

## Bash + coreutils, <s>60</s> 49 bytes

<s>`echo "scale=10100;4*a(1)"|bc -l|tr -d '\\\n'|cut -c$(($1+2))`</s>

```
bc -l<<<"scale=$1+9;4*a(1)-3"|tr -dc 0-9|cut -c$1
```

Improved by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis). Thanks!

The index is one-based.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 73 bytes

thanks to @aditsu for increasing my score by 2 bytes

Finally an algorithm that can complete under 2 seconds.

```python
n=10**10010
a=p=2*n
i=1
while a:a=a*i/(2*i+1);p+=a;i+=1
lambda n:`p`[n+1]
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/xuf3qa)

Uses the formula `pi = 4*arctan(1)` while computing `arctan(1)` using its taylor series.

Comment: Quite speedy. 1-indexing is not native to python, though. Last I recall (admittedly I've been inactive for a while), consensus was that functions need to be defined, e.g. `f=lambda n:...`.

Comment: Almost every lambda here are anonymous (you can search answers in Python in this site)

Comment: [Relevant meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7615/4098). Seems to be in violation of Rule 1 and 3 (after running your code, there is no way to capture the function reference; the function definition would need to be typed out for each input (``(lambda n:`p`[n+1])(1)``, ``(lambda n:`p`[n+1])(2)``, ...).

Comment: You can't run the code directly. It is akin to placing `import` statements beforehand, just that this makes some global variables beforehand.

Comment: `i=3
while a:a=i/2*a/i;p+=a;i+=2` for 4.

Comment: @primo that looks like your answer xd

Comment: Same alg: Leibniz Series (derived from `arctan(1)`), Euler Transform ([Appendix A](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18988/4098)). Counting backwards is self-correcting, and slightly shorter.

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Luis*

```
YPiEY$GH+)
```

This solution utilizes 1-based indexing

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WVBpRVkkR0grKQ&input=MTAwMDE)

[All test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YApZUGlFWSRAR0grKQpEVA&input=MQoyCjMKNAoxMQoxMDEKMTAwMQoxMDAwMQ)

**Explanation**

```
YP  % Pre-defined literal for pi
iE  % Grab the input and multiply by 2 (to ensure we have enough digits to work with)
Y$  % Compute the first (iE) digits of pi and return as a string
G   % Grab the input again
H+  % Add 2 (to account for '3.') in the string
)   % And get the digit at that location
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh yea I guess the output is already a string. Doh!

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh I never actually thought of that. I always use `YP` in my testing of the symbolic toolbox

Comment: Is YP actually allowed? The question says it's allowed if it supports <=10k digits

Comment: @Suever OP stated "up to" rather than "at least". To my understanding that means supporting >10k is forbidden.

Comment: @Suever Yeah, I think I may be, tho I can't resist doing it lol. I deleted my Sage answer just because of that.

Comment: @Suever Oh nice! I'll un-delete it :-)

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica 30 bytes

```
RealDigits[Pi,10,1,-#][[1,1]]&
```

---

```
f=%

f@0
f@1
f@2
f@3
f@10
f@100
f@599
f@760
f@1000
f@10000
```

1
4
1
5
8
8
2
4
3
5

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 32

```
7e4,-2%{2+_2/@*\/2e10005+}*sq~)=
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=N2U0LC0yJXsyK18yL0AqXC8yZTEwMDA1K30qc3F-KT0&input=MTAwMDA) (it's a bit slow)

Answer (score 4):

## Sage, <s>32</s> 25 bytes

```
lambda d:`n(pi,9^5)`[d+2]
```

My first answer in a language of this kind.

`n` rounds `pi` to 17775 digits.

Comment: You need the `print` call, or else this is a snippet which only works in the REPL.

Comment: This works for (theoretically) any input: [`lambda d:\`n(pi,digits=d+5)\`[-4]`](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVRIsUrI0yjI1EnJTM8sKbZN0TbVTIjWNYnl5eLlStMwNAACTQBOcAy7&lang=sage)

Comment: @Mego there aren't "99999" runs?

Comment: @Mego busukxuan is right, that fails as early as 760, 761, 762, 763.

Comment: Then bump up the extra digits: [`lambda d:\`n(pi,digits=d+9)\`[-8]`](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVRIsUrI0yjI1EnJTM8sKbZN0bbUTIjWtYjl5eLlStMwNAACTQBO9AzD&lang=sage)

Comment: @Mego but then there will be even longer "9" runs. I'm not sure if doubling the length can make it universal, but I think not even that can do it, due to the Infinite Monkey Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem

Comment: @busukxuan If you model the uncomputed digits of π as random, you certainly expect arbitrarily long runs of 9s (and we have no reason to expect the real π to be any different, though we have not proven this), but you only expect a run of 9s as long as its position with vanishingly small probability (though again, we haven’t proven that the real π doesn’t behave unexpectedly). We have found runs of at least nine 9s, which I think is enough to break the `[-8]` proposal.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com), <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
10([|<.@o.@^)>:
```

Takes an integer *n* and outputs the *n*<sup>*th*</sup> digit of pi. Uses zero-based indexing. To get the *n*<sup>*th*</sup> digit, compute pi times 10<sup>*n*+1</sup>, take the floor of that value, and then take it modulo 10.

### Usage

The input is an extended integer.

```
   f =: 10([|<.@o.@^)>:
   (,.f"0) x: 0 1 2 3 10 100 599 760 1000
   0 1
   1 4
   2 1
   3 5
  10 8
 100 8
 599 2
 760 4
1000 3
   timex 'r =: f 10000x'
1100.73
   r
5
```

On my machine, it takes about 18 minutes to compute the 10000<sup>*th*</sup> digit.

### Explanation

```
10([|<.@o.@^)>:  Input: n
             >:  Increment n
10               The constant n
           ^     Compute 10^(n+1)
        o.@      Multiply by pi
     <.@         Floor it
   [             Get 10
    |            Take the floor modulo 10 and return
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
⌊10^# Pi⌋~Mod~10&
```

## SageMath, 24 bytes

```py
lambda n:int(10^n*pi)%10
```

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I tried that, but Mathematica seems to require a space between `Pi` and `⌋` (or between `#` and `⌋` if the multiplication is flipped), so the saving disappears.

Comment: Actually it works in the Mathematica Online (I had been using the console version), so I’ll take it, I guess.

Comment: These should be separate answers. Though they use the same strategy, they are nowhere near the same language.

Comment: @Mego The [policy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1003/39242) I found does not say answers in different languages cannot count as very similar. (The answer suggesting that was not accepted.) Are you referring to another policy or just a preference?

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, 312 bytes

```clj
(fn[n](let[b bigdec d #(.divide(b %)%2(+ n 4)BigDecimal/ROUND_HALF_UP)m #(.multiply(b %)%2)a #(.add(b %)%2)s #(.subtract % %2)](-(int(nth(str(reduce(fn[z k](a z(m(d 1(.pow(b 16)k))(s(s(s(d 4(a 1(m 8 k)))(d 2(a 4(m 8 k))))(d 1(a 5(m 8 k))))(d 1(a 6(m 8 k)))))))(bigdec 0)(map bigdec(range(inc n)))))(+ n 2)))48)))48)))
```

So, as you can probably tell, I have no idea what I'm doing. This ended up being more comical than anything. I Google'd "pi to n digits", and ended up on the [Wikipedia page for the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula). Knowing just barely enough Calculus(?) to read the formula, I managed to translate it into Clojure.

The translation itself wasn't that difficult. The difficulty came from handling precision up to n-digits, since the formula requires `(Math/pow 16 precision)`; which gets huge really fast. I needed to use `BigDecimal` everywhere for this to work, which *really* bloated things up.

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn nth-pi-digit [n]
  ; Create some aliases to make it more compact
  (let [b bigdec
        d #(.divide (b %) %2 (+ n 4) BigDecimal/ROUND_HALF_UP)
        m #(.multiply (b %) %2)
        a #(.add (b %) %2)
        s #(.subtract % %2)]
    (- ; Convert the character representation to a number...
      (int ; by casting it using `int` and subtracting 48
         (nth ; Grab the nth character, which is the answer
           (str ; Convert the BigDecimal to a string
             (reduce ; Sum using a reduction
               (fn [sum k]
                 (a sum ; The rest is just the formula
                       (m
                         (d 1 (.pow (b 16) k))
                         (s
                           (s
                             (s
                               (d 4 (a 1 (m 8 k)))
                               (d 2 (a 4 (m 8 k))))
                             (d 1 (a 5 (m 8 k))))
                           (d 1 (a 6 (m 8 k)))))))
               (bigdec 0)
               (map bigdec (range (inc n))))) ; Create an list of BigDecimals to act as k
           (+ n 2)))
      48)))
```

Needless to say, I'm sure there's an easier way to go about this if you know any math.

```clj
(for [t [0 1 2 3 10 100 599 760 1000 10000]]
  [t (nth-pi-digit t)])

([0 1] [1 4] [2 1] [3 5] [10 8] [100 8] [599 2] [760 4] [1000 3] [10000 5])
```

Comment: I realized later that the standard operators actually work on big decimals, so the shortcuts at the top are unnecessary. I mount fix this at some point. That'll probably knock off ~50 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 253 bytes

```
(defmacro q[& a] `(with-precision ~@a))(defn h[n](nth(str(reduce +(map #(let[p(+(* n 2)1)a(q p(/ 1M(.pow 16M %)))b(q p(/ 4M(+(* 8 %)1)))c(q p(/ 2M(+(* 8 %)4)))d(q p(/ 1M(+(* 8 %)5)))e(q p(/ 1M(+(* 8 %)6)))](* a(-(-(- b c)d)e)))(range(+ n 9)))))(+ n 2)))
```

Calculate number pi using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula). Have to redefine macro `with-precision` as it's used too frequently.

You can see the output here: https://ideone.com/AzumC3
1000 and 10000 takes exceeds time limit used on ideone, *shrugs*

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk – 270 bytes

Relies on the identity `tan⁻¹(x) = x − x³/3 + x⁵/5 − x⁷/7 ...`, and that `π = 16⋅tan⁻¹(1/5) − 4⋅tan⁻¹(1/239)`. SmallTalk uses unlimited precision integer arithmetic so it will work for large inputs, if you're willing to wait!

```
|l a b c d e f g h p t|l:=stdin nextLine asInteger+1. a:=1/5. b:=1/239. c:=a. d:=b. e:=a. f:=b. g:=3. h:=-1. l timesRepeat:[c:=c*a*a. d:=d*b*b. e:=h*c/g+e. f:=h*d/g+f. g:=g+2. h:=0-h]. p:=4*e-f*4. l timesRepeat:[t:=p floor. p:=(p-t)*10]. Transcript show:t printString;cr
```

Save as `pi.st` and run as in the following test cases. Indexing is one based.

```
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 1
1
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 2
4
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 3
1
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 4
5
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 11
8
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 101
8
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 600
2
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 761
4
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 1001
3
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 10001 -- wait a long time!
5
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/), 338 bytes

This implementation is based on the [Chudnovsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm), one of the fastest algorithms to estimate pi. For each iteration, roughly 14 digits are estimated (take a look [here](https://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky/) for further details).

```
f=lambda n,k=6,m=1,l=13591409,x=1,i=0:not i and(exec('global d;import decimal as d;d.getcontext().prec=%d'%(n+7))or str(426880*d.Decimal(10005).sqrt()/f(n//14+1,k,m,l,x,1))[n+2])or i<n and d.Decimal(((k**3-16*k)*m//i**3)*(l+545140134))/(x*-262537412640768000)+f(n,k+12,(k**3-16*k)*m
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/DoubleStupendousBoastmachine)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) (Chrome 67+), <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes

```javascript
n=>`${eval(`for(a=c=100n**++n*20n,d=1n;a*=d;)c+=a/=d+++d`)}`[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pU7LisIwFN37FUHKcNNk0lTRoZTrYnZ@gzg0JKlU4k1pRYRhvr3Gx8L9nMXhPBbnHM3FjHbo@vMnReenFifCTZP9@osJ0LRxAIMWS60pz4WgfKFJOiypNjm6mluBpkAnhHAN/2t2tJ/qnZaslGwh2TKJu9GJVlUl2df6aV@s9@pkergy3DAbaYzBqxAP0MJ3d9jSGa48oZ7N3kv4z0EOj13iagyd9fA6UnI1@D6YlBQ/oHgh2Tz7UPM0Pt0A)

Using \$\pi/2=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k!/(2k+1)!!\$ (same logic used by Leaky Nun's Python answer, but thanks to the syntax of JS that makes this shorter). Input is passed to the function as a BigInt. 2 bytes can be removed if 1-based indexing is used:

```javascript
n=>`${eval(`for(a=c=100n**n*20n,d=1n;a*=d;)c+=a/=d+++d`)}`[n]
```

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) (Chrome 67+), <s>90</s> 89 bytes

```javascript
n=>`${eval(`for(a=100n**++n*2n,b=a-a/3n,c=0n,d=1n;w=a+b;a/=-4n,b/=-9n,d+=2n)c+=w/d`)}`[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY5BTsMwEEX3PYVVVWgcO7aTQlEUTRfsOENVFNdxqlRmHCVVWwlx9mCgCy7ALP7Mn7d5J3uxkxv74ZxTbP3c4Uy4bVYf/mIDNF0cwWJhDGWZEJSVJA9oc6vXJB0aki0WVF/RikNtNeaPiadVJSCwJO4EXnXb8M9mR/u53hnJCslKydbp@C4mxVNVSfa8@a33NHv1bge4MdwyF2mKwasQj9DBS398pTPceJp6sfgL4X/UOfwYEVdT6J2Hu2LB1eiHYNNHv4HiWrLl6kEtk9b8BQ)

Using \$\pi/4=\arctan(1/2)+\arctan(1/3)\$. Input is passed to the function as a BigInt. 2 bytes can be removed if 1-based indexing is used:

```javascript
n=>`${eval(`for(a=100n**n*2n,b=a-a/3n,c=0n,d=1n;w=a+b;a/=-4n,b/=-9n,d+=2n)c+=w/d`)}`[n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>262</s> 260 bytes

```
import java.math.*;int c(int n){BigInteger p,a=p=BigInteger.TEN.pow(10010).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));for(int i=1;a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)>0;p=p.add(a))a=a.multiply(new BigInteger(i+"")).divide(new BigInteger((2*i+++1)+""));return(p+"").charAt(n+1)-48;}
```

Used [*@LeakyNun's* Python 2 algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84465/52210).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/eqlwsu)

```
import java.math.*;
class M{
  static int c(int n){
    BigInteger p, a = p = BigInteger.TEN.pow(10010).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
    for(int i = 1; a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; p = p.add(a)){
      a = a.multiply(new BigInteger(i+"")).divide(new BigInteger((2 * i++ + 1)+""));
    }
    return (p+"").charAt(n+1) - 48;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.print(c(0)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(1)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(2)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(3)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(10)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(100)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(599)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(760)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(1000)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(10000));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1, 4, 1, 5, 8, 8, 2, 4, 3, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

## Maple, 24 bytes

```
 trunc(10^(n+1)*Pi)mod 10
```

Test cases:

```
> f:=n->trunc(10^(n+1)*Pi)mod 10;
> f(0);
  1
> f(1);
  4
> f(2);
  1
> f(3);
  5
> f(10);
  8
> f(100);
  8
> f(599);
  2
> f(760);
  4
> f(1000);
  3
> f(10000);
  5
```