# Print the n-th digit of pi

Tags: code-golf, math, pi

**Task**

Given an input `n`, calculate the n-th decimal digit of pi

**Rules**

- Answer can be a full program or a function.
- Input must be taken from stdin or from function arguments.
- Output must be either sent to stdout, the return value of a function, or written to a file.
- all `n` values between 0 and 20000 must be supported (can be between 1 and 20001 for 1-indexed languages).
- **Built-ins to calculate pi cannot be used**. This includes pi constants (e.g. `math.pi` in Python) and built-in functions that return either the value of pi, or the n-th digit of pi. This means that an algorithm which calculates pi, or the n-th digit of pi must be implemented in your answer.
- Digits must be calculated at runtime.

First digit (0-th or 1-th, depending on the language) is 3.

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

**EDIT:**

This is not a duplicate of 'Find the n-th decimal of pi', since that challenge allowed built-ins. This one is focused around actually implementing an algorithm to find the digits, rather than relying on built-ins.

Comment: The ban of built ins probably makes this different enough.

Comment: [linking for the sake of completeness](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84444/find-the-nth-decimal-of-pi). In my opinion it's a dupe, because a lot of those answers can be copy pasted to this challenge. But not voting to close just yet.

Comment: base16 allowed?

Comment: @dwana No, it has to be in base10

Comment: This is a completely different challenge without the use of builtins.  From what I can see all of the answers to the other question are using builtins and don't apply here.

Comment: @cleblanc, it seems to me that five of the (undeleted) answers to the other question use series expansions such as the Leibniz series, and one uses an built-in for arctan which isn't technically in violation of the spec of this question. That makes 6 out of 13 answers which could be copied across unmodified.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>182</s> 65 bytes

```python
a=p=2*10**20004
i=3
while a:a=i/2*a/i;p+=a;i+=2
print`p`[input()]
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EF0E/3)**

Uses the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) to calculate 20000 correct digits (plus a handful to allow the algorithm to maintain accuracy) then prints the requested digit.

---

Previous (182):
["The Spigot Algorithm For Pi"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975006) of Stanley Rabinowitz and Stan Wagon has the added bonus that it will work for any `n` when implemented as a generator

```python
p=lambda n,r=3,a=0,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=3,f=3,i=0:i>n and r or p(n,e,*[((2*b+a)*f,b*d,c*f,d+1,(b*(7*d)+2+(a*f))/(c*f),f+2,i),(10*(a-e*c),10*b,c,d,((10*(3*b+a))/c)-10*e,f,i+1)][4*b+a-c<e*c])
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EFWc)** Reaches Python's default recursion limit for the 117th digit.

Here is a non-recursive version for 198 bytes:

```python
def p(n):
 a=i=0;b=c=d=1;e=f=3
 while i<=n:
     r=e
     if 4*b+a-c<e*c:g=10*(a-e*c);e=((10*(3*b+a))/c)-10*e;b*=10;i+=1
     else:g=(2*b+a)*f;h=(b*(7*d)+2+(a*f))/(c*f);b*=d;c*=f;f+=2;d+=1;e=h
     a=g
 print r
```

**[repl.it](https://repl.it/EFXf)**

(first indent space, second indent tab), the digits could, of course, be generated by yielding `e` at the start of the `if` clause instead of tracking the last digit with `r`.

Comment: Nice implementation of that algorithm, but by using a different algorithm it can be more than 110 bytes shorter in Python 2, [as shown by the two Python 2 algorithms here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84444/find-the-nth-decimal-of-pi).

Comment: Yeah, I know, am implementing arctan...

Comment: link is broken... fascinating implementation. the explanations that i found dont look like that. they use arrays and vectors, which you dont

Comment: @donbright Thanks I have updated the broken link to point to a stable link at jstor.org

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>260</s> 258 bytes

```
import java.math.*;int c(int n){BigInteger p,a=p=BigInteger.TEN.pow(20010).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));for(int i=1;a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)>0;p=p.add(a))a=a.multiply(new BigInteger(i+"")).divide(new BigInteger((2*i+++1)+""));return(p+"").charAt(n)-48;}
```

[Copy from my answer here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97362/52210) Java's built-in `Math.PI` has a precision of 15 decimal points, so I was already forced to use an algorithm for the other challenge anyway..

Used [*@LeakyNun's* Python 2 algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84465/52210).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/30GI5d) (The ideone can't handle the last two test cases, but it works within 2 sec in the Eclipse IDE.)

```
import java.math.*;
class M{
  static int c(int n){
    BigInteger p, a = p = BigInteger.TEN.pow(20010).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
    for(int i = 1; a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; p = p.add(a), i++){
      a = a.multiply(new BigInteger(i+"")).divide(new BigInteger((2 * i++ + 1)+""));
    }
    return (p+"").charAt(n) - 48;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.print(c(0)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(1)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(2)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(3)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(4)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(11)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(101)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(600)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(761)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(1001)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(10001)+", ");
    System.out.print(c(20001));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 8, 8, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2
```