# Mix pi and e to make pie!

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, pi

Everybody knows *pi* the mathematical constant, the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter.

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510...
```

You probably also know *e* the mathematical constant, the base of a natural logarithm.

```
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369996...
```

But... do you know *pie*? It is one of the most important constants (to me). It is the digits of *pi* and *e* interleaved.

```
32.1741185298216852385485997094352233854366206248373...
```

As a decimal expansion:

```
3, 2, 1, 7, 4, 1, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 8, 2, 1, 6, 8, 5, 2...
```

This is [OEIS sequence A001355](https://oeis.org/A001355).

> KEYWORD: nonn,base,**dumb**,easy

It is a very dumb sequence.

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes a **non-negative integer n** and outputs the **nth digit of pie**.

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- Your solution must work for at least 50 digits of each constant which means it should work for at least a **100 terms of the sequence** (please, *try* not to hardcode :P).
- The output for 2 or 3 is **not a decimal point**.
- Your solution **can either be 0-indexed or 1-indexed** but please specify which.
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions that compute this sequence are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

#### Test cases

These are 0-indexed.

```
Input   Output

1       2
2       1
11      8
14      6
21      4
24      9
31      5
```

In a few better formats:

```
1 2 11 14 21 24 31
1, 2, 11, 14, 21, 24, 31

2 3 12 15 22 25 32
2, 3, 12, 15, 22, 25, 32
```

Comment: According to the OEIS, the keyword `dumb` simply means uninteresting with no properties special to it.

Comment: I think hardcoding is the best solution in Python...

Comment: You might just be able to get there with [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org)...

Comment: @Downvoter Any reason, perhaps?

Comment: One could argue that the result is `pei`, not `pie`

Comment: I didn't do the down vote, but maybe because you didn't ask this on 3/14 ;)

Comment: At 1:59pm, @txtechhelp? ;)

Comment: Hardcoding the output is a [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/46076). Are you intending to override that by saying "please, *try* not to hardcode, or should the hardcoded answers be deleted as exploiting a standard loophole.

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, 50 bytes

1-indexed

```
(Riffle@@(#&@@RealDigits[#,10,5!]&/@{Pi,E}))[[#]]&
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: it's easy. It takes 120(5!) elements of each and riffle them

Comment: Nice! I tried to beat your solution by avoiding `Riffle`, but my solution comes up one byte short: `RealDigits[If[OddQ@#,Pi,E],10,#][[1,Ceiling[#/2]]]`&

Comment: This appears not to work. It returns a single digit.

Comment: @DavidC Yes!.."outputs the nth digit of pie" Exactly! why did you downvote???

Comment: Oops, my bad!  I misunderstood the goal.

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, <s>154</s> <s>147</s> 146 bytes, NO HARDCODING OR USE OF BUILTIN CONSTANTS

This solution calculates *e* and *pi* using infinite series and stores them in arbitrary-precision fixed-point integers (Haskell's built-in `Integer` type and its `Rational` extension).

```
import Data.Ratio
s n=product[n,n-2..1]
r=[0..164]
f n=(show$round$(*10^50)$sum[[2*s(2*k)%(2^k*s(2*k+1)),1%product[1..k]]!!mod n 2|k<-r])!!div n 2
```

Ungolfed:

```
import Data.Ratio

semifact :: Integer -> Integer
semifact n = product [n, n-2..1]

pi_term :: Integer -> Rational
pi_term i = semifact (2*i) % (2^i * semifact (2*i+1))

--requires 164 terms to achieve desired precision
pi_sum :: Rational
pi_sum = 2 * (sum $ map (pi_term) [0..164])

--requires 40 terms to achieve desired precision
e_sum :: Rational
e_sum = sum [1 % product [1..k] | k<-[0..40]]

-- 51 digits are required because the last one suffers from rounding errors 
fifty1Digits :: Rational -> String
fifty1Digits x = show $ round $ x * 10^50

pi51 = fifty1Digits pi_sum
e51  = fifty1Digits e_sum

-- select a string to draw from, and select a character from it
pie_digit n = ([pi51, e51] !! (n `mod` 2)) !! (n `div` 2)
```

0-indexed. Accurate for input 0-99, inaccurate for input 100-101, out-of-bounds otherwise.

Explanation:

Calculates *pi* using [this infinite series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14116/63189). Calculates *e* using the classical [inverse factorial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). Theoretically these aren't the ideal formulas to use, as they aren't very terse in terms of bytecount, but they were the only ones I could find that converged quickly enough to make verification of accuracy feasible (other sums required hundreds of thousands if not millions of terms). In the golfed version, *e* is calculated to a much higher precision than necessary in order to minimize bytecount. Both constants are calculated to slightly more digits than necessary to avoid rounding errors (which are responsible for the awkward tail of incorrect values).

The constants are calculated as arbitrary precision integer ratios (`Rational`), then multiplied by 10^50 so that all necessary digits remain intact when the ratio is converted to an (arbitrary precision) integer (`Integer`). This also avoids the issue of avoiding the decimal point in the numbers' string representations, which the function alternatively draws characters from.

Answer (score 8):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 749 bytes

```
'3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:n 3 r 3 r.[a]Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to The Underground:s 1 r 1 l.Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 4 l.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan "a".[b]Go to Narrow Path Park:n 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:e 1 r 4 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZJPb8IgGMa/yhsv3hr50wI9bst220yc2cF4QKUtsYEGaLp9@o5qXVyzaLIDEJ68/HieF4L81H0/JxgxihBPseAYZXElPKU8FYItBCUpxmQQSJbhRYYpJ4xQzgjChKUCp1kUMadcUIaYSBlDOKOCkYUQgpAsSgKJOWgPndRBmxJkgA@ng3JzD0@qsSF5sRAsLK0P8FYUeq/yDhDUcbhhTZZ6f2wbkNBI75UplYPSDqh46r1S8CB3qi60r5T7GmFTOfcX4l3a2hyUK51tzWGE/babmxFVA75j7rGyDaxadXH1s48MEsPFkWzk9hbiVTpnO1jKUMXJHa/yXRk9xTs3a9XpsK@GmqaWBma7GegCjAVr1NUz/KMNz62qY9W6yf2oTM3FWDRamIZVF3On/k8Nylmy2W1vAm95vfo2f3yk89V07E3fY/4N)

Trying to compute pi or e programmatically in Taxi would be a nightmare, although I'm sure it can be done. Thus, it's *far* shorter to just hardcode the first 100 digits in the sequence. It feels pretty cheap but it's definitely the shortest Taxi code that meets the challenge.

It hard-codes the sequence as strings, takes in `n`, then iterates `n` down and removes the first character in the string each time. When `n=0`, output the first character. This is one-indexed.

Un-golfed / formatted:

```
'3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey: north 3rd right 3rd right.
[a]
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to The Underground: south 1st right 1st left.
Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Fueler Up: south.
Go to Narrow Path Park: north 4th left.
Go to Chop Suey: east 1st right 1st left 1st right.
Switch to plan "a".
[b]
Go to Narrow Path Park: north 4th left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: east 1st right 4th right 1st left.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
žsтžtøJþsè
```

Explanation:

```
žs          Get the first input digits of pi
  тžt       Get 100 digits of e
     ø      Zip them together
      J     Join into a string
       þ    Remove non-digits
        sè  0-indexed index of input in the resulting list
```

0-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/8wNWFiMWX//8W@c9GCxb50w7hKw75zw6j//zEx)

Comment: Too many 05AB1Es... :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Well, 05AB1E is the language with the pi and e builtin...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder There are builtins that's why.

Comment: @totallyhuman no it doesn't.

Comment: @Dorian Your version doesn't work. You're using the legacy version, but `žt` wasn't an infinite list back then, which is why _Okx_ is using the first 100 digits of e in his program. Changing it to the new version of 05AB1E (where both pi and e are an infinite list) still wouldn't work in your current version, because the zip would create pairs and the `J`oin would join those pairs instead of everything. [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7io/tKDu8IPrzP8/CK///NTAE) are still possible by replacing `J` with `S` in the new version however, where `S` makes it a flattened list of chars/digits

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Yes, you're right. I didn't test it enough. I deleted my comment now. I just had 65 in my input box by chance and the code gave the correct result for that.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7io/tK9M7t9Dy84v9/M1MA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 88 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to the base conversion idea of [@EriktheOutgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer).*

```python
lambda n:`int("SVBPXJDZK00YCG3W7CZRA378H4AM5553D52T52ZKAFJ17F4V1Q7PU7O4WV9ZXEKV",36)`[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc/BS8MwGAXw@/6Kz4DQsghN0iw66KFuTlkRq85uVoVW2qwfzHS08eBfX@NBqHh7j/e7vOOXbVrDBx29Dofy470qwcwLNNYjj9llulsv8yQInhfXYqsW@UMs1PlNGN9KKcVS8o3keRKv1kytwozdq/RJ3YXb7CLfXSUZoWLmFy/mbdBtBwhooCvNvvYYZQHz5xPoPzVEQGxDJoDakVNgAUQRMChN5fqJi8zBX9lbJ@vDH8tHlo@sqf5bMbJiZLsfe@zcbSCbpia0wGLqNkoq3KOFVkOKNWBPqPbwjPnDNw)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), 92 bytes

0-indexed. Thanks to Rod for reminding me to switch to `from sympy import*`, which I formerly forgot.

```python
lambda n:sum([('3','2')]+zip(`N(pi,50)`,`N(E,50)`[:47]+'6996')[2:],())[n]
from sympy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZLCsIwEADQvaeY3czYCLVqpQHdufUCMdCKRgfMh7Qu6uWj@FYvzdMzhqa4w6W8Bn@9DRD0@PZkCDeosEG21UcS9WdKonY19@rX039Gb/e2wrbrWmTTaKuI2QS7cDl6GGefZhCfYp6WxcUMAhIgD@Fxp3Vds15AyhImEIWrIypHwuUL)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes

<s>I honestly think the shortest solution is hardcoding, since Python doesn't have useful built-ins.</s>

```python
lambda n:"3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919"[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCsIwEADQq4Ru2kKFzCeZmYJeRF1UtBrQtIRuPH2sqwdv/W6vJWOdj5f6nj63@@Ty2BCCMIAGNEWIu6SBNZiJN6aASP@gGNFHZCUhViFAkmAY4p6orMYCYkEEMLIJeTMjinsZWHPO1zovxSWXsitTfj46P4D3/ejWkvLm0tAeTu0wd6mvPw)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes

Equivalent solution by [@totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman).

```python
'3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919'.__getitem__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCsIwEADQq2SXFqpkPsnMCHoSIbhoaxampWTj6WNdPXj7t723in25P7snBGEAjWiKkE5JI2s0k2BMEZH@QSlhSMhKQqxCgCTRMKYzUVmNBcSiCGBiEwpmRpTOMjB/zXmdW2nzJ@e@bIcrrlR3vOo6D2GCEMab249SmyuTvzz8tAxl7D8)

Comment: Before downvoting, take your time to search for a shorter solution.

Comment: [Equivalent byte count.](https://tio.run/##FchLCsIwEADQq2SXFqpkPsnMCHoSIbhoaxampWTj6WNdPXj7t723in25P7snBGEAjWiKkE5JI2s0k2BMEZH@QSlhSMhKQqxCgCTRMKYzUVmNBcSiCGBiEwpmRpTOMjB/zXmdW2nzJ@e@bIcrrlR3vOo6D2GCEMab249SmyuTvzz8tAxl7D8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @totallyhuman Thanks

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent :P

Comment: Found a possibly shorter solution with `sympy.mpmath`, editing if it becomes shorter

Comment: I found a shorter solution with mpmath and posted it below

Comment: [using `from sympy import*`](https://tio.run/##HcZLCsIwEADQvaeY3czYCLVqpQHdufUCMdCKRgfMh7Qu6uWj@FYvzdMzhqa4w6W8Bn@9DRD0@PZkCDeosEG21UcS9WdKonY19@rX039Gb/e2wrbrWmTTaKuI2QS7cDl6GGefZhCfYp6WxcUMAhIgD@Fxp3Vds15AyhImEIWrIypHwuUL) you can save a lot of bytes

Comment: [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcexCsIwEADQvV9x2@VoLLVqpQHdXP2BGGhEowcmDUkd6s9HEN/24jI/p9AVd7iUl/XXm4Wg8tsLLXCDEjskU384ijE3Z5GbyHLX0ij/Pf2m1XZvauyHoUfSnTJSEOlgKvZxSjPkxccFbIZc3JSAgQMkGx53sW5bUhXExGEGlrg6onSCqXwB "Python 2 – Try It Online") - cmon man :P (or what Rod said)

Comment: @Rod Forgot to update from my testing ground :))) - I was convinced mine was shorter and I didn't know why it was over 100 - By mistake I copied my "sandbox" try instead of my golfed approach. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: @StepHen Actually 92

Comment: The equivalent solution that you edited in is actually equivalent code, not equivalent byte count. :P

Comment: Actually hardcoding would be shorter (88 bytes) using base 36: `\`int("SVBPXJDZK00YCG3W7CZRA378H4AM5553D52T52ZKAFJ17F4V1Q7PU7O4WV9ZXEKV",36)\`.__getitem__` or `lambda n:\`int("SVBPXJDZK00YCG3W7CZRA378H4AM5553D52T52ZKAFJ17F4V1Q7PU7O4WV9ZXEKV",36)\`[n]`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks.

Comment: @totallyhuman Lol I saw your comment and understood it but I completely forgot to fix, because I was laughing about my own mistake. Thanks for editing in!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>83</s> 80 bytes

0-indexed.

```python
lambda n:('%d'*51%(*b' )4bD4&6UcF^#!U+B>0%"WK\<>0^GO9~1c]$O;',))[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVC5TsNAEK1QJHfcDYLhCN4Ng@QrNhtwCoSgoEgVUeSQ1kkMKyWO5aSBgl83M4ul7EhvjvfmabTl9/ZrXYR1no7rpV5lcw1FT7jtudvp@m3RyVzYlwdRdvwS3cbD2ev0@uRyePd81PfaVx8Xp@/jvaf@mTd9G6jWr986n01uBo@HLko5Kib1emE2kMIoxAB9TDAi9PEBu9QryjyNmz60ObKoKBL0CCOaM8s8KxxoXtdSMUVAQkZeDWkttBVn364l1jAgjBtlQDxr2D7ZWfKFimQJBa/GRCtr5NmLlL0hblSKNGrilJUptkIvl2KzrYSWkKaQQb6uQCMVpoAfUwr@CISVLkWOUOnicyF8z5P8HIfFhpU7ogf/vgbBve@7CLkwUtZ/)

There are some non-printable characters in there that can't be seen properly in a browser.

This works by building the tuple `(32, 17, 41, 18, 52, ...)` from the ASCII codes of the characters in the hardcoded bytestring. The tuple is converted to the string `'3217411852...'`, from which we select the right digit.

Answer (score 4):

## Polyglot, 108 bytes

```c#
n=>"3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919"[n]
```

Works in:

- C#
- JavaScript

---

I think this is the shortest you can do in C# seeing as it is 252 bytes to find the [Nth decimal of pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138560/38550).

Comment: JS polyglot :-)

Comment: @Arnauld Updated :)

Comment: Polyglot for Java, but with `->`

Comment: @Okx Updated, for some reason I forgot you could index into strings in Java...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Oh wait, that's because you can't... you've got to use `.charAt` I believe

Comment: Would this also be a TypeScript polyglot? And JSX?

Comment: This isn't a Java Polyglot! You can't index into Non-Array Objects in Java.

Comment: This technically works but I downvoted because it's a) not very competitive and b) extremely boring and trivial.

Comment: works also on julia with `->` (like java)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It's C# and JavaScript when are they ever competitive? And boring and trivial maybe but would you rather I did a 500 byte answer in C# that was clever? No because that conflicts with point 1. This is as short as it gets...

Comment: If it's the shortest answer then that's a different situation, but it's not particularly competing in this challenge anyway.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Did you also downvote the [Seed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138569/38550) then?

Comment: Does it really matter to you that much? For what it's worth, no, I did not, because Seed is not trivial. I did however down vote the corresponding Befunge answer. Now please stop bothering me about it; if you really care that much about the answer score you can ask on meta how people are "supposed" to vote.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I know you can vote however you like I was asking to see if I can improve my answer in any way that will satisfy you. However, as both of your criteria for downvoting conflict with this submission, short and trivial, it appears I will never be able to do that...

Comment: Why would I down vote short submissions? This is code golf after all. I am just opposed to hard coding in some cases, though I don't always down vote it because there is too much hard coding to down vote.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I phrased that wrong I meant, you want it to be short and none trivial and in this case it isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), 6015 bytes

```
105 41100973201674650461227976639700390615120600528953176107701316721890649738810349651490948904154731057172335535600875054878204557287393379815378680878571406244365932330202793040308312687924242319799562985464135998860369933720376853281630432469462831217924775601393232895404104191613314969008627719099002734936685651970933027922574843126481552407811220371545812798263882325951724505132794956253992779856191832909434513683936955184871247159313261417328850445886987045814618325821125417040265540589403338721758954467831926977078444612065747526326682314711350486782090838673475876960125016098416460032667015813053483457246043486676622061645094043655351781242050448580132075920324099742699960838361839038297355120817832056960516761862493176616153258281345538652844974811030063414112136642097000574165433957710342430709643110444042577685157477268110199017600011209827070311299268347100419887111107237908884608557593677163764286026624394674781868689858494991328505977301270068505397030743037416430245399054325956185200430657008806539374392625804513081295070438243600044274289109395357299275275193717501822777898664715885427884193864182834402097958423697356485767670945673525604620701482288023981110598866625872386643941558021439168402392304238271452444124214301243311025121833097491087918320170873313832323794851508364788578530614246140801266858481189449278157296335592848066512127882306035576754122325822200069362884409931190620435627809384380203617488253034370361172908245852012086081807945576657014184275798330804532115103840313004678040210379846666674881048346897213048386522262581473085489039138251061251160730845385869281787222083186331344552658814775998639661361866503862291670619153718574270905089351133527806484519543645501497150560454761284099358123613642350160410944676702481576280832672884549762767667090615809061739499629798396737503512011645776394176807352443544839957773371384141101627375926404212619777658374366513665083032140398814384622434755543347503025479743718569310129255927244046638238401670388409731849963600790867434678993019370132638962549859363736476668247251402420832876258626149639101811361047924632565285870213656416957893835899254928237592711662454838295046528789720146967061486405916116778722736283489123195985053535189375957277052428901645131462087039117212488839670735246752589931585405440449333046667938628384693216121067951290025349082277568986632815062532963505690244579740140120806885104683071514922412748240497612209609661707922754236180441892543545377867355182682381812487973645406703590150722720330526173957597156314579144484166520730013480681064941752984345205140917291104888971742824066713606933406657345121342075268990055328274845008936364502884461548416337689565392911129757761902576946104722487260155373897552821908338346641549478063474748830482136404008215583192489320750526753663943267086203954602839906762640389978523894333743126288529975769945319614142422443068420170103245659109689433597701350198280212250954698442638475209618790055335813263132865176791663235801963797561493995544185124734214257034901773781134331460320221759556924556747571745834582344275416625351302153332814233497096345055392255809024712740720006219615340819493781244665414077298346378966540544979367367978334759985048507214749726072645238624803791884339024844989975370042133733339339038567691571361407296615851372112592532463329778465699812822089846474961581380707849259093905314170108054540333209088059730272087864344697983074458088984533095183089310714804468718319244214535941276969904638763288063417624586766891798378622613765728303031397998644194508610598078718347204813844240434145846888722334194516524032354042557957058092854659539699310565707914118281251563405735083553254856313838760124953245573676126601070861004186509621892263623745673900572829301771299438501543213489182375655869072568437776298051260531944785904157204006430131566234389896821642210616326951771496269255716808352415001187083781128619236455170025989777631182990311607133740812107138446626302353752098982590371714623080450836912706275397973009559314275978915463843159370230629290376520494894845680706499809017211545204670148071902560908658269183779180493590025891585269507219866461550160579656755846447951259951641828495549544791046179035585611272240116822105364823082512055639047431280117805724371019657801828634946412396263504315569042536942671358095826696817513115447079645898107923447321583282886740680340887700198072304400536529418546232473450984945589794448490331085275232352881571706521961358975744067916422124670374397682877259664913100427726059898474024964867713698696116581478101206003313106174761699804016604950094008714907179862448792216891309734208815522069346791369498202430302292199779590583788518283934542807403049256936179914953814019565550264909025345322516061595136601312434888871667940394250767164496543418483237896796108764367721411969986710930448108645039275082356457263454340220118278471652962484104099512207532103709146426640958406853240342441810465024550617909657901698718289260589269758398513490424434162831332785821428006396653475356712733072469052427934231406388810607688824035522285626563562286337967271308076321307276537761026788485320280603487776428017017298356181654076403306265118978333909378403193559129146468182910851996415072056976175613473847242292911071040966109905552914332596680497156169349277079292398091020434667210493868422848588893205157133171899819212153010393580099455957808703428739456223073813663954919146593698106305501988107196273527346690785289909397140611634970017071011599022429384594426022933102487171920965595473754661194965266230932928905708783854897164127767575976566931916632077914904360565095752466049885656187054491320449776951484812738806536727562344348761718424255018794271994537719709226236497935053971406685810778014002594041715040546776952342303797267458880802314841325359844565479173256964507237937290466116935912176054052746039378370966040054779443633371806403649852746347690237831260027483859907620684197542069045517397230169577918374265220969534695931904
```

The Seed equivalent to my Befunge answer. Like I mentioned there, the Befunge program this outputs does not work on TIO because TIO seems to have internal line wrapping at 80 characters.

Comment: How? Just... how?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193325/61379 Outgolfed

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>420</s> <s>417</s> <s>413</s> <s>404</s> <s>380</s> 358 (calculated) & <s>115</s> 110 (hardcoded) bytes

Calculated (**<s>420</s> <s>417</s> <s>413</s> <s>404</s> <s>380</s> 358**):

```java
import java.math.*;n->{int i=1,x=99;BigDecimal e,f=e=BigDecimal.ONE;BigInteger p,a=BigInteger.TEN.pow(x);for(p=a=a.add(a);i<x;)e=e.add(e.ONE.divide(f=f.multiply(f.valueOf(i++)),new MathContext(x,RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));for(i=1;a.compareTo(a.ZERO)>0;)p=p.add(a=a.multiply(a.valueOf(i)).divide(a.valueOf(i+++i)));return n==1?50:((n%2<1?p:e)+"").charAt(-~n/2);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hVFdTxsxEHy/X2EhVfI2F8OF9gGMQRRStRIkiI@XVlW13O0lDne25fjCIZT@9dRH2qYvhMed0ezMzs5wgX3ryMyKh5WunfWBzSImagxT8V4meYXzObtEbZ4Tpk0gX2JObBQnlk/Rs5xHlBmQCVsmbB4w6JyNmFFsZfrHzx2pVZa26uBAftKTc8p1jRWjtFSkNoAYj4Yd/zVaTMgzl6LajOJ2OBLOPvIWZGk9dwoVCiwKjiD1USuBFL3M1C0ShV7ognipSlE3VdCueuKlWGDV0LjkutcDSA09xrvC9MxGjzbwNr22jSm0mVzagsSX04vPP@@uANaO8QaJIre1Q0@3lqP4Nrwew/GeBKfcOkqM9M8NN24Af/Pg/xF6utvtKTTexLpUdvJx75Bz825wlJ24Q4Lezg6IruPTwPu/zO4A5HIVa3bNfRU7/lP1wuqC1fE//Cb4GP77D4TuOTdP80C1sE0QLuKhMtyInGfQfeo1drCVzbaLsw/bd79hvV29v1Yvk@XqNw)
[Prove it outputs correct result for required 100 items.](https://tio.run/##fVNrT9swFP3Or7iqNMleW5N3YoJBMJg2abSIsS97aDKJQ80SJ0ucUoS6v945TUcrQJOSWPfE955z7rXv@JyPy0qou/TXShZVWWu4MxgpuJ6RtzEA7O/DJTdwmYGeCbh50GKclK3Se0nOmwYuuFSPewBSaVFnPBEw6UKAZMZrSJDBQeHYQEvzmqfRXMsEJqCAwUqNjx67LZLZowWjND6Vt2cikQXPQYwyJtgWINPJeff/o6G6FTVUI862Ibk@n5CqvEcLHGdljSrGGSc8TRHHsTxcxFgwsY5FV4ikci5TgTKWkaLNtazyB5SROc9bMc2QHA4xHilxbwzq2bvScCw0WoyujPVUqtuLMhXkw8mn9z@/XGLcMxoPMSdJWVS8Ftcl4uTr@dUUH1kxrljVSzGSntj4lg3jf3r4roSh7GrXQre1AsWYfexbBwipN86hfVwdCDwcDDDpOn2i0fiP2ndwvFzFfaOr9iY3jd70e17KFAozLPRZ18bAtx/AcT@pHgBTJU2MrfRKNEaimc7AdezQs@3Id2jk2IFZ3cj3Ip/S0KKe6zuO2wFuEDhW4HiRG7peFLq244Y@dfzAgE7kRdQL7ZD6YWg7gUdD16KUum5gIGrTQbwrIuF50uZc76rY7Fi3eH1ULDNP2zJfM6TeArxMHDJQxJw/3Gcve5aHRouClK0mleHTuUKDJ98H3/UAhs/7sMl/LXPLuUl9LuI/uaelnq1vVMMLcfwqMxG/W5436EXVzXVarv4C)

Hardcoded: (**<s>115</s> 110 bytes**):

```java
"3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919"::charAt
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY/PTsMwDIfvfQprpxaJqonzz5s48ADssiPiELLCUtq0arNJCPXZSyq4Uk6WP@tnf27szd73Qx2a88fiu6EfIzSJlZ2Nl/LukLnWThM8WR@@MvAh1uObdTUcUwfuYkdweaIQikMGcwZTtNE7OEJ4gGWHnGnBmJGcDGcqVTRSGEmkKxIoOccVoFK8UlwY1CiMRsZRS@JSJciNMCQ00yS1ZlwJ0lgREaJKiBjt9vvV4zEuyWC4vrbp/K/Frfdn6JJ6foqjD@/PL7ZYvU@fU6y7sr/Gckg8tiEPpctZsT7x15RvTtl2mInt3f@c3k7jT3rO5uUb)

0-indexed

-9 and -5 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.
-24 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

> - Your solution must work for at least 50 digits of each constant which means it should work for at least a **100 terms of the sequence** (please, *try* not to hardcode :P)
> - Built-in functions that compute this sequence are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged

You've asked for it.. ;)

Java's built-in `Math.PI` and `Math.E` are doubles, which have a max precision of just 16. Therefore, we'll have to calculate both values ourselves using `java.math.BigInteger` and/or `java.math.BigDecimal`.
Since I've already [calculate PI before in another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97365/52210), I've used that same code using `BigInteger`. The algorithm for Euler's number uses `BigDecimal` however.
The resulting `p` and `e` are therefore: `31415...` and `2.718...`.

Could probably golf it by only using `BigDecimal`, but was giving some incorrect answers for PI, so I now use both `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`.

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.math.*;           // Required import for BigDecimal and BigInteger
n->{                          // Method with integer as parameter and char as return-type
  int i=1,                    //  Start index-integer at 1
      x=99;                   //  Large integer we use three times
  BigDecimal e,               //  Euler's number
             f=e=BigDecimal.ONE;
                              //  Temp BigDecimal (both `e` and `f` start at 1)
  BigInteger p,               //  PI
             a=BigInteger.TEN.pow(x);for(p=a=a.add(a);
                              //  Temp BigInteger (where both `p` and `a` starts at 10^99*2)
  
       i<x;)                  //  Loop (1) 99 times (the higher the better precision)
    e=e.add(                  //   Add the following to `e`:
       e.ONE.divide(f=f.multiply(f.valueOf(i++)),
                              //    First change `f` by multiplying it with `i`
        new MathContext(x,RoundingMode.HALF_UP))))
                              //    And then add 1/`f` to `e`
                              //    (RoundingMode is mandatory for BigDecimal divide)
  for(i=1;                    //  Reset `i` back to 1
      a.compareTo(a.ZERO)>0;) //  Loop (2) as long as `a` is not 0
    p=p.add(                  //   Add the following to `p`:
       a=a.multiply(a.valueOf(i))
                              //    First change `a` by multiplying it with `i`,
          .divide(a.valueOf(i+++i)));
                              //    and dividing it by `2*i+1`
                              //    And then add this new `a` to `p`
  // We now have `p`=31415... and `e`=2.718...
  return n==1?                // If the input (`n`) is 1:
          50                  //  Return 2
         :                    // Else:
          ((n%2<1?            //  If `n` is divisible by 2:
             p                //   Use `p`
            :                 //  Else:
             e)               //   Use `e` instead
    +"")                      //  Convert BigDecimal/BigInteger to String:
        .charAt(-~n/2);}      //  And return the `(n+1)//2`'th character in this string
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help you but my [C# algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138560/38550) for calculating pi came in at 8 bytes shorter than your Java version.

Comment: Note though to get it to work properly for this question change `(d+=2)` to `++d` and `return p%10+1` to just `return p%10`.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Feel free to make a C# answer for this challenge. :) Although you'll also have to calculate Euler's number. My answer is kinda for lolz anyway, since hardcoding the output is shorter anyway..

Comment: I'm in the process of making a none hardcoded one. I just posted it to see if it could help you was all :)

Comment: The C# answer came in at 377 bytes with some more golfing possible, maybe some of it will help? Though I don't know for sure.

Comment: `You've asked for it.. ;)` Hey, I like your first one better. I got way more hardcoded answers than I expected...

Comment: You can save 9 bytes in your calculated answer by using `charAt(n+1>>1)` and 5 bytes in your hardcoded version by using a method reference `"..."::charAt`.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks! And been able to golf 21 more bytes by using `.valueOf` instead of `new BigDecimal` (not sure why I didn't had that in my original answer tbh..), and 1 more by using `i+++i` instead of `i-~i++`. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 113 bytes

1-indexed

```
=MID("3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919",A1,1)
```

`PI()` is only accurate up to 15 digits.  Similar for `EXP(1)`.

<s>60</s> 42 byte solution that works for Input `<=30`
(-18 bytes thanks to @Adam)

```
=MID(IF(ISODD(A1),PI(),EXP(1)/10)/10,A1/2+3,1)
```

Comment: The basic concept in your second approach can be shortened to 46 bytes by only having the pi/e choice inside the `if(...)` statement: `=MID(IF(ISODD(b1),PI(),EXP(1)/10)/10,b1/2+3,1)` .Can't get around the imprecision of `pi()` and `exp()`, though

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
žssžt‚øJ'.Ks<è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L7i4qP7Sh41zDq8w0tdz7vY5vCK//8NTQE)

---

This answer is 0-indexed.

```
žs              # pi to N digits.
  sžt           # e to N digits.
     ‚øJ        # Interleave.
        '.K     # No decimal points.
           s<è  # 0-indexed digit from string.
```

Comment: I know there are already three other 05AB1E answers, so it doesn't really matter, but you can golf 3 bytes by changing `'.K` to `þ` and remove the `<`. (Not sure why you even included the `<`, since you state your answer is 0-indexed. Your current answer is 1-indexed with the `<`.)

Comment: Hmm.. you can also remove the `,` since the zip does this implicitly, but I see it's than almost exactly the same as the other 10-byte answer..

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), <s>70</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(N([pi,E][n%2],50)*10**(n/2)%10)
from sympy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBLboQwDN1zimxGkyBXzYeBZiS667YXoCyCOrSRIEQMG3p5arvTWHr@Pdux8759L8keY/txTGEePoNI15g2@S67HOGt79LJ9nDRqjS6LGV6tupktCrGdZnFfZ/zLuKcl3Urj3FZRRQxiU6DAQvGgKnAolmBM@Dr/ppX6i0inJ9ezzDKqFRRLLd4bztHFdBAhWjgBS7oe9QUrR@@Y10xepQGNCJ25yzl/xkOa2qMaEaqcMh2bJE2zG64j0WsH0yLeeJQ14b/4zHbsG2RUfFUx3NJHE/6Y3nk@L7gHUWYJhnadhB0lQAD3eUnZknLgphDliOsIX3dpNFa4Tt@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
Éi<;žtë;žs}þθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cGemjfXRfSWHVwPJ4trD@87t@P8fAA)

Similar to Magic's answer, but kinda different.

Explanation:

```
Éi<;žtë;žs}þθ Supports 9842 digits of e and 98411 digits of π
É             a % 2
 i    ë   }   if a==1
  <            a - 1
   ;           a / 2
    žt         e to a digits
              else
       ;       a / 2
        žs     π to a digits
           þ  keep chars in [0-9] in a
            θ a[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 55 bytes

```
" ®v4bØUî6UcF^#ß&6$Îø%\"Wí;<>0^GO9G1c]$O;"cs gU
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IiCudjRi2FXuNlVjRl4j3yY2JAbO+CVcIlcf7TsZPD4cMF5HTzlHGjEHHmNdJE87EyJjcyBnVQ==&input=MTE=) Contains a few unprintables.

Works by replacing each character in the string with its charcode, then returning the digit at the correct index. The string was generated by this program:

```
r"..(?=[^0]0)|25[0-5]|2[0-4].|1..|.(?=[^0]0)|..|."_n d
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ciIuLig/PVteMF0wKXwyNVswLTVdfDJbMC00XS58MS4ufC4oPz1bXjBdMCl8Li58LiJfbiBk&input=IjMyMTc0MTE4NTI5ODIxNjg1MjM4NTQ4NTk5NzA5NDM1MjIzMzg1NDM2NjIwNjI0ODM3MzQ4NzMxMjM3NTkyNTYwNjIyODQ4OTQ3MTc5NTc3MTI2NDk3MzA5OTkzMzY3OTU5MTki)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 63 bytes

1-indexed

```
a(n)=replace(string(BigFloat(n%2>0?π:e)),'.',"")[ceil(Int,n/2)]
```

Converts pi or e to a string, removes the decimal place, and then calls the appropriate digit.  Returns a character representation of the digit.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## Seed, <s>5852</s> 5794

Based on TehPers Befunge answer.

```
105 113002164871590739314987829049307960037656198834866427236905121954115803425132377811017261267508985918460516699110604069383390959259813211529503372875273808710588124346256307646667819637622583266174711430236542978713371651111138161258814014430791036278292414499656452941169156830257154682891945427168323349789659414918954432721496930284898425790960909241894284781315857049329769224542864680353681534575933422424767707487267105729647869707615701969946632447899025935146610872657847217500147458582162977840688029783675330301220720997622926460983429318136766448664249339408547350925381367609377956773869746595751981270619213926147211890869963881664082555405185043676206172128177189246682247058574292315899935090905437591661266740559405162222996969611028558290091641009922497490272073602109698144136237139892288758564286335997806260176733841267995620802629495311018527105600614517192092649739617993355354764787635487444533658359428565687080154517757890270592773372024921163684788486949109705417597693762970920021249476121718487310885214065572289535961346215683364612315264822079329585462764945219095679916070353286147709600972570614120233113128790126662286156057686903720942137873912511576516301011227356138489027470697247933585954842450741358944012216071769761815733661875419652839052931663415505744712631746787832014322014868591150702573172166945669229230913363344728435313054200429998131904807363769656763488962394934163037250505543518966376704416506376321611183458869639917973770286152983694797090148271251013631504215211063321591324191669491956643311240521006341404267009756225607360091610388650359124819175883509292439414777620417167522685091490259040136036034579692518124798164708926188495203908126898658681865909050531795557967108988591574556866175888346903123079427257115921330028144573070329426929531076740133942295248077792078687841078079268719526879909788542680179524275827358784127273168527872136974672731344708599614215281119934065639520745234349293757970245111171645337101665479132283486591886003364231440299524048129365242579269735889557760669994751103041672868435202250671067797684169074938720299249334705611438978473321117244865600759558291122236484729311642571499634395815652244856036306309426007390684666411239172295850545146441402560560341332328380709310752195557971123590340315335700317013293851268994688275799911771016064582194514876381367454879798122437554725457606331047947374904420197286393544275845842428580614721866647174706186991857454507274563175804998237200744486630048509506143395191487837350195267021654643538881849734231141725424601330485671509495305148131743810493387517147034390010671970517110205867361059474884617856208037099248888176490940290206562546475055852738977573593904440085870522989324367348662198800983879197171460362503731088514814079681375712029106737219687292822832109515671205430310190195987438406367288649547279607011336560384368751332286717619791748985553772693409536049147249735256714714024639568250305940497144973962564739882059896415826530266878391650198495604496902130260192048771738287910630368379535990532534781447331851939134456545892027046327917478474665636031407046424166662224021038524518495928222266639887065627494062967545357424609779938336142901480061872078034629454218589211641784224052477683545808790001800789690114038324361179370588354779145068239226196064382427132818933211646651925556744151561592584028445615402230429197821863456537957514864271133762278972184204869644394521345416271355631691230134619361522785486931887108980824977655507783434249228188856167617108716815094123730600710952108190016969333162591813869968264515792463284254698981261829244948079958090972029228009509584596285072135655480768099128872214767174088557681133949254945492690159492733827441038586327672595878146092413446635826008953390852510674046712247097336867698827720756888212247984007467030021498051100766545723521829074239408920419228250849112577718015149186696163811124496295326839833968618977237298392606857935004740275480306823203459402487279114142809512031125908797313635314972863814303513678473099927026607274900456721755543827098812499754976223002068988166928549986537496305328253011857088410803897580533534109872057730526662956704744519240370047288779478242394065841217642437006215862683465340567540141567908382219161706192517414918920335949928316037480173726078040746055914732675899449554957974703336123447175047024451331108027464919186072451108622235369696655603590410141636686651842707160470522293863594778186952018113745140884964015958604111363959827254006218576819095970777536217638180423889634131748541027983145892759706009491393182243795048903475541887656616509860914555116317017006096855080419242968307668243354850411304416190687499212061972410926839498652918205097786610428363995506942432312411823427047186868840577006626729855054434535548056834448216246518404910539196129433524592691043628016754842890872507304906318742343175154206452151706945249818234640798419739099879992464416047867973147679669193814805760372826774933145903193782399649588923478706079107924185454258124307881293104633301338073776691416142537130145576268465288334517657616632085092685517319761353655436962877242874726395604578641629542918465198557048233824201655936372542110027024362703019743929091896294865287339787424383206745979183701439427840308590723461600323162160013212640322512322745821468600689724015806074498945821524378781714871793675698107420867876597774494057787557965469877984960511884501039590623229374018088813765629152405059007172424233594237883453270762239632440547727976805269692785605606401953257035710157327757004025470677546239616027587603888642814609779889799831508662735822095183804904610021893861075323086016909910447437995018169256183487254051119590377469311351028312018776850026116029689211988391328901764154505776555092490963288792
```

Comment: Nice job! I'm a bit curious about how you golfed it.

Answer (score 2):

## Malbolge Unshackled (20-trit rotation variant), 3,64E6 bytes

Size of this answer exceeds maximum postable program size (eh), so the code is [located in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/codegolf-submissions/raw/master/138547.mu) (note: Don't copy the code using CTRL+A and CTRL+C, just rightclick and click "Save destination element as...").

### How to run this?

This might be a tricky part, because naive Haskell interpreter will take ages upon ages to run this. TIO has decent Malbogle Unshackled interpreter, but sadly I won't be able to use it (limitations).

The best one I could find is the fixed 20-trit rotation width variant, that performs very well, **calculating (pretty much) instantly**.

To make the interpreter a bit faster, I've removed all the checks from Matthias Lutter's Malbolge Unshackled interpreter.

```c
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* translation = "5z]&gqtyfr$(we4{WP)H-Zn,[%\\3dL+Q;>U!pJS72Fh"
        "OA1CB6v^=I_0/8|jsb9m<.TVac`uY*MK'X~xDl}REokN:#?G\"i@";

typedef struct Word {
    unsigned int area;
    unsigned int high;
    unsigned int low;
} Word;

void word2string(Word w, char* s, int min_length) {
    if (!s) return;
    if (min_length < 1) min_length = 1;
    if (min_length > 20) min_length = 20;
    s[0] = (w.area%3) + '0';
    s[1] = 't';
    char tmp[20];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        tmp[19-i] = (w.low % 3) + '0';
        w.low /= 3;
    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        tmp[9-i] = (w.high % 3) + '0';
        w.high /= 3;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (tmp[i] == s[0] && i < 20 - min_length) i++;
    int j = 2;
    while (i < 20) {
        s[j] = tmp[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    s[j] = 0;
}

unsigned int crazy_low(unsigned int a, unsigned int d){
    unsigned int crz[] = {1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1};
    int position = 0;
    unsigned int output = 0;
    while (position < 10){
        unsigned int i = a%3;
        unsigned int j = d%3;
        unsigned int out = crz[i+3*j];
        unsigned int multiple = 1;
        int k;
        for (k=0;k<position;k++)
            multiple *= 3;
        output += multiple*out;
        a /= 3;
        d /= 3;
        position++;
    }
    return output;
}

Word zero() {
    Word result = {0, 0, 0};
    return result;
}

Word increment(Word d) {
    d.low++;
    if (d.low >= 59049) {
        d.low = 0;
        d.high++;
        if (d.high >= 59049) {
            fprintf(stderr,"error: overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return d;
}

Word decrement(Word d) {
    if (d.low == 0) {
        d.low = 59048;
        d.high--;
    }else{
        d.low--;
    }
    return d;
}

Word crazy(Word a, Word d){
    Word output;
    unsigned int crz[] = {1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1};
    output.area = crz[a.area+3*d.area];
    output.high = crazy_low(a.high, d.high);
    output.low = crazy_low(a.low, d.low);
    return output;
}

Word rotate_r(Word d){
    unsigned int carry_h = d.high%3;
    unsigned int carry_l = d.low%3;
    d.high = 19683 * carry_l + d.high / 3;
    d.low = 19683 * carry_h + d.low / 3;
    return d;
}

// last_initialized: if set, use to fill newly generated memory with preinitial values...
Word* ptr_to(Word** mem[], Word d, unsigned int last_initialized) {
    if ((mem[d.area])[d.high]) {
        return &(((mem[d.area])[d.high])[d.low]);
    }
    (mem[d.area])[d.high] = (Word*)malloc(59049 * sizeof(Word));
    if (!(mem[d.area])[d.high]) {
        fprintf(stderr,"error: out of memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (last_initialized) {
        Word repitition[6];
        repitition[(last_initialized-1) % 6] =
                ((mem[0])[(last_initialized-1) / 59049])
                    [(last_initialized-1) % 59049];
        repitition[(last_initialized) % 6] =
                ((mem[0])[last_initialized / 59049])
                    [last_initialized % 59049];
        unsigned int i;
        for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
            repitition[(last_initialized+1+i) % 6] =
                    crazy(repitition[(last_initialized+i) % 6],
                        repitition[(last_initialized-1+i) % 6]);
        }
        unsigned int offset = (59049*d.high) % 6;
        i = 0;
        while (1){
            ((mem[d.area])[d.high])[i] = repitition[(i+offset)%6];
            if (i == 59048) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return &(((mem[d.area])[d.high])[d.low]);
}

unsigned int get_instruction(Word** mem[], Word c,
        unsigned int last_initialized,
        int ignore_invalid) {
    Word* instr = ptr_to(mem, c, last_initialized);
    unsigned int instruction = instr->low;
    instruction = (instruction+c.low + 59049 * c.high
            + (c.area==1?52:(c.area==2?10:0)))%94;
    return instruction;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Word** memory[3];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        memory[i] = (Word**)malloc(59049 * sizeof(Word*));
        if (!memory) {
            fprintf(stderr,"not enough memory.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j=0; j<59049; j++) {
            (memory[i])[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Word a, c, d;
    unsigned int result;
    FILE* file;
    if (argc < 2) {
        // read program code from STDIN
        file = stdin;
    }else{
        file = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    }
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    a = zero();
    c = zero();
    d = zero();
    result = 0;
    while (!feof(file)){
        unsigned int instr;
        Word* cell = ptr_to(memory, d, 0);
        (*cell) = zero();
        result = fread(&cell->low,1,1,file);
        if (result > 1)
            return 1;
        if (result == 0 || cell->low == 0x1a || cell->low == 0x04)
            break;
        instr = (cell->low + d.low + 59049*d.high)%94;
        if (cell->low == ' ' || cell->low == '\t' || cell->low == '\r'
                || cell->low == '\n');
        else if (cell->low >= 33 && cell->low < 127 &&
                (instr == 4 || instr == 5 || instr == 23 || instr == 39
                    || instr == 40 || instr == 62 || instr == 68
                    || instr == 81)) {
            d = increment(d);
        }
    }
    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    unsigned int last_initialized = 0;
    while (1){
        *ptr_to(memory, d, 0) = crazy(*ptr_to(memory, decrement(d), 0),
                *ptr_to(memory, decrement(decrement(d)), 0));
        last_initialized = d.low + 59049*d.high;
        if (d.low == 59048) {
            break;
        }
        d = increment(d);
    }
    d = zero();

    unsigned int step = 0;
    while (1) {
        unsigned int instruction = get_instruction(memory, c,
                last_initialized, 0);
        step++;
        switch (instruction){
            case 4:
                c = *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized);
                break;
            case 5:
                if (!a.area) {
                    printf("%c",(char)(a.low + 59049*a.high));
                }else if (a.area == 2 && a.low == 59047
                        && a.high == 59048) {
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 23:
                a = zero();
                a.low = getchar();
                if (a.low == EOF) {
                    a.low = 59048;
                    a.high = 59048;
                    a.area = 2;
                }else if (a.low == '\n'){
                    a.low = 59047;
                    a.high = 59048;
                    a.area = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 39:
                a = (*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)
                        = rotate_r(*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)));
                break;
            case 40:
                d = *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized);
                break;
            case 62:
                a = (*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)
                        = crazy(a, *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)));
                break;
            case 81:
                return 0;
            case 68:
            default:
                break;
        }

        Word* mem_c = ptr_to(memory, c, last_initialized);
        mem_c->low = translation[mem_c->low - 33];

        c = increment(c);
        d = increment(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like more than 3646 bytes

Comment: @H.PWiz forgot the E, sorry

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), <s>124</s> 97 bytes

```nim
import sugar
t(x=>($(7*"""L?J$rg$"79n*i.71&<B@[>)!Y8l:.pUo4GZ9c0a%"""[x/%2].ord))[x%%2+1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wc34gqL8ZIUSjTQrBTBLo8JKITOvRNNKITkjsUhTwZZLQSE1OSNfIU3DUBPBNkJiGyNLGKKoMtFcWlqSpmtxMyUztyC_qEShuDQ9sYirRKPC1k5DRcNcS0lJyUfe3kulKF1CRUnM3DJPK1NP2NxQzcbJIdpOUzFS0iLHSq9AWlQ-NF_AxD3KMtkgUVUQqCm6Ql_VKFYvvyhFUzO6QlXVSNswFmrXAigFpQE)

*-27 thanks to @Steffan*

Comment: So great to see nim here again!

Comment: Saves three bytes to use `sugar` plus `=>`: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY49qsJQEEZ7VzFYJYWQ-bl3ZgK6ERGR8KIpNBKvkMKd2AjiotyNUQL6qnM43xRzvR-a_e25PnZtBSmrS_hY1pfQHFJeQrXbdDnMJwB_1a6FOsP86_Tj_DvgvyvJH-dUz-x5afbHtktwOm833SRl_XwxZUIVRAvkRhgHsgWx4K6FCwcifgeOkYpIYqwspozEGpxCHCKZmIuielBFiuLKhbszxyE5-nTZr8YfbiNGvgA). (don't count the `t(` and `)` at the beginning and end)

Comment: And here's [100 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wc34gqL8ZIUSjTQrBTBLo8JKITOvRNNKITkjsUhTwZZLQSE1OSNfIU3DUBPBNkJiGyNLGKKoMtFcWlqSpmtxMyUztyC_qEShuDQ9sYirRKPC1k5DRcNcS0lJyUfe3kulKF1CRUnM3DJPK1NP2NxQzcbJIdpOUzFS0iLHSq9AWlQ-NF_AxD3KMtkgUVUQqCm6Ql_VKFYvvyhFUzO6QlXVSNswFmrXAigFpQE) taking the idea of unprintables from Lynn's answer.

Comment: Incredible golfing!

Comment: Oops sorry that's only 97 bytes, I forgot to exclude the `t(` and `)` from the bytecount

Comment: Oh, no problem. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 + [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/constants.html), 109 Bytes

0-indexed
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcw9CsMwDEDhuT6FNstNCfkhS6EnMR4CsRsVLAvFS0/v4rXbBw@efOtZeG0tacmQJe/1BMpStN5NlvGQ67XN5ogJErJ7mpsocUVrx08hRm/XxYbBX1VRyHkKQ2fsSkWBgBh053fE5bHNLjjPwbW/NE9TXyck134)

```
from mpmath import*
mp.dps=51
print(''.join(['32']+[str(pi)[i]+str(e)[i]for i in range(2,51)])[int(input())])
```

Beat hardcoding by 5 bytes!!
But could probably be better. But beating hardcoding makes me feel good :)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 35 bytes

```
@.i`u+/*GHhyHyK^T99rJ^2T0Z`sm/K.!dJ
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40.i%60u%2B%2F%2aGHhyHyK%5ET99rJ%5E2T0Z%60sm%2FK.%21dJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A11%0A14%0A21%0A24%0A31&debug=0)

Since Pyth doesn't have built-in arbitrary precision pi and e constants, I calculate them directly.

Calculating pi:

```
u+/*GHhyHyK^T99rJ^2T0
```

This uses the following recurrence continued fraction to compute pi: `2 + 1/3*(2 + 2/5*(2 + 3/7*(2 + 4/9*(2 + ...))))`. I got it from [another PPCG answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/512/20080). It is derived in equations 23-25 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html).

I calculate it from the inside out, ommitting all terms beyond the 1024th, since the later terms have little effect on the number, and I maintain 99 digits of precision to make sure the first 50 are correct.

Calculating e:

```
sm/K.!dJ
```

I sum the reciprocals of the first 1024 numbers, to 99 digits of precision.

Then, I convert both numbers to strings, interlace them, and index.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

```python
lambda n:`7*ord('L?J$rg$"79n*i.71&<B@[>)!Y8l:.pUo4GZ9c0a%'[n/2])`[n%2+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKsFcK78oRUPdR97eS6UoXUJFSczcMk8rU0/Y3FDNxskh2k5TMVLSIsdKr0BaVD40X8DEPcoy2SBRVVA9Ok/fKFYzITpP1UjbMPZ/QVFmXolCbmKBRpqOQlFiXnqqhqGBgabmfwA)

Contains some unprintable ASCII characters. flornquake saved two bytes.

Comment: This breaks e.g. for n=64, n=65. Not sure what the best way is to fix that, maybe `lambda n:('%02d'%ord('...'[n/2]))[n%2]`, though there's probably something better.

Comment: @flornquake darn, you're right. I wrote a fix that's one byte shorter. can't think of anything better

Comment: Nice. Here's something even shorter, based on your idea: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKsFcK78oRUPdR97eS6UoXUJFSczcMk8rU0/Y3FDNxskh2k5TMVLSIsdKr0BaVD40X8DEPcoy2SBRVVA9Ok/fKFYzITpP1UjbMPZ/QVFmXolCbmKBRpqOQlFiXnqqhqGBgabmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

**MATLAB, 93 Bytes**

```
n=input('');
e=num2str(exp(1));
p=num2str(pi);
c=[];
for i=1:length(p)
 c=[c p(i) e(i)];
end;
c(n)
```

A simple explanation is that this first converts e and pi to strings, then goes through a for loop concatenating the digits. Here, c is pie, p is pi, and e is e.

I have also broken this up into several lines for readability, but the actual code is all on one line with minimal spacing.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks, I've been browsing Code Golf for quite a while, and finally decided to give it a go myself.

Comment: This has some issues, mainly that it appears to take no input. You need to modify your function so that given the integer, `n`, it will produce the `nth` digit of the Pie sequence. You can also reduce your bytecount by reducing your variable names to a single char

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the variable names for byte count. As for the nth digit, am I just supposed to define n=?, or am I supposed to take a user input?

Comment: Looks like you already figured it out, but you should prompt the user for input, however, it is not necessary to have any formatting attached to that prompt, so you an use `input('')` in place of `input('n')`

Comment: Thanks, I made that edit as well now and it reduced the byte count by 1.

Answer (score 1):

## C# + [BigDecimal](https://github.com/CognitioConsulting/BigDecimal), <s>377</s> 372 bytes

```c#
d=>{if(d%2<1){d/=2;int l=++d*10/3+2,j=0,i=0;long[]x=new long[l],r=new long[l];for(;j<l;)x[j++]=20;long c,n,e,p=0;for(;i<d;++i){for(j=0,c=0;j<l;c=x[j++]/e*n){n=l-j-1;e=n*2+1;r[j]=(x[j]+=c)%e;}p=x[--l]/10;r[l]=x[l++]%10;for(j=0;j<l;)x[j]=r[j++]*10;}return p%10;}else{CognitioConsulting.Numerics.BigDecimal r=1,n=1,i=1;for(;i<99;)r+=n/=i++;return(r+"").Remove(1,1)[d/2]-48;}}
```

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen.*

No TIO link because of the external library, unfortunately C# doesn't have a built in `BigDecimal` class so this external one will have to do. Probably some golfing still possible but no time right now.

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
namespace System.Linq
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<int, long> f = d =>
            {
                if (d % 2 < 1)
                {
                    d /= 2;

                    int l = ++d * 10 / 3 + 2, j = 0, i = 0;
                    long[] x = new long[l], r = new long[l];

                    for (; j < l;)
                        x[j++] = 20;

                    long c, n, e, p = 0;

                    for (; i < d; ++i)
                    {
                        for (j = 0, c = 0; j < l; c = x[j++] / e * n)
                        {
                            n = l - j - 1;
                            e = n * 2 + 1;
                            r[j] = (x[j] += c) % e;
                        }

                        p = x[--l] / 10;
                        r[l] = x[l++] % 10;

                        for (j = 0; j < l;)
                            x[j] = r[j++] * 10;
                    }

                    return p % 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    CognitioConsulting.Numerics.BigDecimal r = 1, n = 1, i = 1;

                    for (; i < 99;)
                        r += n /= i++;

                    return (r + "").Remove(1,1)[d/2] - 48;
                }
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Console.Write(f(i));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can ditch the parenthesis around `x[j++]/e` at `c=(x[j++]/e)*n` for -2 bytes; Also, I think you can remove both `+""` at the two return statements and return an int instead of string, and then add `-48` at the second return statement to convert char to int output (for -1 byte).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Both work fine thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 402 bytes

```
--->+>->+>>+>+>>->->+>+>+>-->->+>+>>>->->+>+>>+>+>->+>>+>+>>+>->->>-->>>->+>>+>->->->->+>+>>->+>->+>>->>-->->>>->>>+>->->->->>->>+>-->+>+>+>>+>>>+>->->>+>>->->+>+>->>+>->->>+>->->++[[>+++<-]<+++]>>+>->+>>+>->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>->+>->+>>->->->>+>->->->->+>>->>>>+>+>+>>>+>>->+>>->+>->>->+>->+>>->>+>+>>+>+>+>->>>+>+>>>>+>->+>+>->+>+>>>->>>+>>>>+>->>>+>>>>->->->->->>+>,[<[-]>[<+>-]<-]++++[<+++++++++++>-]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBLCkMxCDyQnZ4gCD2HZPFaKJRCF4WeP08TjTbmI5PJOOb@PV6f5@/xHgMAE9vSqRtmboFIE1z45tK8MCIHCg/XcvYiLVpl2ZyFKAS3aLGCAk6MRHSjht706JymQimjeCgS2L44aodhf/FnfvdO3gAxZ7n8Jc4LT5G9El@kCTpLU0JX92qexFqIYfB1jNsJ)

Input as character code (e.g. "A" = 65)

[Try it online with digit input!](https://tio.run/##VVBBDgIxCHwQO970RPgI6UFNTIyJBxPfX4HSUqFbKJ0Ow94@1@f78b2/egcgJP7Zsg2Ru2OmVRz1haW4cKDMKtKTK9EDNGA7ylc0okm4SDcp2IpRI1XbiNHYQpMSNZnKNw0bBZYumb2n4HzxJ37NTjkAiVS7@ktSF5miZiU5QraZMtIETZRpmZ3ZUBzBoiWHDajMrqQxK@t44ie0wUb/BKfeL@cf)

code:

```
build a value list (3217411852... reversed and each digit incremented by four)
--->+>->+>>+>+>>->->+>+>+>-->->+>+>>>->->+>+>>+>+>->+>>+>+>>+>->->>-->>>->+>>
+>->->->->+>+>>->+>->+>>->>-->->>>->>>+>->->->->>->>+>-->+>+>+>>+>>>+>->->>+>
>->->+>+>->>+>->->>+>->->++[[>+++<-]<+++]>>+>->+>>+>->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>->+>->+
>>->->->>+>->->->->+>>->>>>+>+>+>>>+>>->+>>->+>->>->+>->+>>->>+>+>>+>+>+>->>>
+>+>>>>+>->+>+>->+>+>>>->>>+>>>>+>->>>+>>>>->->->->->>+

>,                      get input
[                       while input > 0
  <[-]                      set next previous cell = 0
  >[<+>-]                   copy input cell to that cell
  <-                        and decrement it
]
++++[<+++++++++++>-]    add 44 to it
<.                      print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `H`, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
∆I₁∆ĖYi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQSCIsIiIsIuKIhknigoHiiIbEllnigbBpIiwiIiwiMzEiXQ==)

-1 thanks to tybocopperkettle

Interleaves the first 100 digits of pi and e, then prints the value at the index

Comment: You can remove the `⁰` because of implicit input. [Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIIiwiIiwi4oiGSeKCgeKIhsSWWeKBsGkiLCIiLCIzMSJd)

Comment: (Oops, wrong link. [This](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJIIiwiIiwi4oiGSeKCgeKIhsSWWWkiLCIiLCIzMSJd) is the right one)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 52 bytes

Uses `-rbigdecimal/math` flag to require BigMath.

```ruby
->n{BigMath.send([:PI,:E][n%2],n*2).to_s(?E)[n/2+2]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcmu0km5RUmZ6SmpyZm5ijn5uYkmGUuwiN9ulpSVpuhY3TXTt8qqdMtN9geJ6xal5KRrRVgGeOlausdF5qkaxOnlaRpp6JfnxxRr2rprRefpG2kaxtVC9lgWlJcUKbtGGsQrKCkZcUJ4RiGcI4xmCJS3gXBMQ1wxiwIIFEBoA)

### Explanation

Ungolfed:

```ruby
->n{
  BigMath.send([:PI, :E][n%2], n*2)
    .to_s(?E)[n/2+2]
}
```

`[:PI, :E][n%2]` chooses which method to send to BigMath, `PI` or `E`. We call that method with `n*2` as the precision argument because of a quirk when n=1 (it returns an Integer instead of a BigDecimal, and the former doesn’t take a string argument to `to_s`).

`to_s(?E)` converts the number to a string in engineering notation, then we get the `n/2+2`th character (+2 to skip over the `0.`), which is the digit we want.

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 45 bytes

```
(₃β{Nhj\CΓℚφᚺK$mᚠ"2oξ:{rm(/ᛂ})
```

neim isn't made for decimal numbers

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/X@NRU/O5TR/mTpj0Ye7UxdVAouHD3Cl7gAK9fkBibUZWjPO5yY9aZgFlZgBxH1Bw8vm2h7N2ARmbvFVyH85aoGQEksg/t8@quihXA8ju0gcSsx7ObgKqmV6rCeRM/f/f0BAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 105 bytes

```
3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919&0g,@
```

Does not work on TIO because it seems to wrap lines internally at 80 characters for some reason. You can get it to work on TIO by putting each digit on a new line, and having the `&0g,@` after the `3` on the first line.

Comment: Works fine on TIO with Befunge 98: https://tio.run/##Hcg7DsJAEATRqzgiwtJO9/w64yxIxhkiIeD0y0JUpXc/Hu/neezq/fX575yElZt1QA3LVXZ4h1RDzgD4A2ZiJLxZ9C4aWCFELkR7y8tKUWVIV3FIInORTJdxXm9zjm37Ag

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) + [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/), 78 bytes

```js
(n,m=math.create({number:"BigNumber"}))=>`${n%2?m.e:m.pi}`.match(/\d/g)[n/2|0]
```

Zero indexed and works up to 128 numbers (max input of 127).

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=
(n,m=math.create({number:"BigNumber"}))=>`${n%2?m.e:m.pi}`.match(/\d/g)[n/2|0]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.0/math.min.js"></script>
<input type=number min=0 value=0 oninput="O.innerHTML=this.value.length>0?f(+this.value):''"><pre id=O>3
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB (w/ Symbolic Toolbox), <s>89</s> 82 bytes

By making use of the Symbolic Toolbox, this answer provides an output without hardcoding the values of pi and e.

As a fun bonus this code as an input can take either a single index, or an array of indices and will simultaneously provide the output value for all index values provided (e.g. providing 1:10 will output the first 10 values).

```
a=char(vpa({'exp(1)';'pi'},51));
a(a=='.')=[];
n=input('');
a(9+fix(n/2)+56*mod(n,2))
```

<sup>(new lines added for readability, not required for execution so not included in byte count)</sup>

Unfortunately the Octave version used by TIO doesn't support symbolic inputs to the `vpa` function, so can't provide at TIO link.

In MATLAB indexing into the return vector from a function is not possible in the same way as with Octave which means this is a full program rather than just an anonymous function. The program will ask for an input `n` during execution - this is a one indexed value for which element is required. At the end of the program the value is implicitly printed.

For the program we use the `vpa` function which provides to 51 decimal places the value of `pi` and `exp(1)` (e). This is done symbolically to allow theoretically infinite precision. To expand for more than 100 elements, simply increase the value `51` in the code to increase the range.

Wrapping `vpa` in `char` (i.e. `char(vpa(...))` ) is necessary to convert the output of the function to a string rather than a symbolic value. The resulting output is the string:

```
matrix([[2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369996], [3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937511]])
```

This includes both e and pi to 51 decimal places - enough to allow 100 digits of our output (we have to do a little extra dp than required to avoid printing out rounded values)

In order to index in to this mess, we need to at least get rid of the decimal points so that both strings of digits are contiguous. Originally I used a simple regex replacement of anything which is not a digit with nothing. However I can save 7 bytes by only getting rid of the decimal point using the code:

```
a(a=='.')=[];
```

resulting string is now:

```
matrix([[271828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369996], [314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937511]])
```

This contains all the digits we need with both pi and e chunks in consecutive indexes.

We can then convert the supplied index such that odd numbers access the pi chunk and even numbers access the e chunk using the calculation:

```
9+fix(n/2)+56*mod(n,2)
```

Accessing that (those) index (indices) in the above string will provide the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 47 Bytes

> *Note: due to the length of constants stored in Excel and Google Sheets, this solution is only accurate to 20 digits, accordingly*

Anonymous Worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs that digit of Pie to the calling cell

```vb
=Mid(.1*If(IsOdd(A1),Pi(),.1*Exp(1)),3+A1/2,1
```

### Hardcoded Version, 112 Bytes

This version fully meets the program specification, but is generally not fun.

Anonymous Worksheet function that returns the nth digit in the **1-indexed** list of pie

```vb
=Mid("3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919",A1,1
```

Comment: Dividing by 10 to shift decimal point (in stead of SUBSTITUTE) can save a few of bytes in first solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 148 bytes

```
g(x,n)==floor(numeric(x)*10^n)::INT rem 10
f(n:NNI):NNI==(m:=digits((n+4)::PI);x:=n quo 2;if n rem 2=1 then r:=g(%e,x)else r:=g(%pi,x);digits(m);r)
```

0 based array. Results

```
(10) -> [f(i) for i in 0..20]
   (10)  [3,2,1,7,4,1,1,8,5,2,9,8,2,1,6,8,5,2,3,8,5]
                                            Type: List NonNegativeInteger
(11) -> f(100001)
   (11)  6
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BFASM](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/asmbf), 142 bytes

```
stk 0
org 0
txt "3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919"
in_ r1
rcl r2,r1
out r2
```

Takes input as ascii character, gives output in form of digit.

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 5971 bytes

Direct translation of my other bfasm answer.

```
+>+[<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,>[-]<[<+>>>>>>>>>>+>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-]<[>+<-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[[>>]+[<<]>>-]+[>>]<[<[<<]>+<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>[>>]<-]<[<<]>[>[>>]<+<[<<]>-]>[>>]<<[-<<]><<<<<<<<<<<<.<<<]<<<[>>+>+<<<-]>>[<<+>>-]>[[-]<<<[-]>[-]>>]<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VhRCsIwDD1QnCcIAc8R@qGCIIIfguevyQpiFYT147VpYVvf2tclS9OmOT2O1/vleb7lTELKKmJPZl6SiDKTiNVUHX4V2l5aSA2cJtnaiRgJm5VqZYKM1Uc/oAHmNVwIzcKI2Y26nQiXEjk9Ue6D02lmP0WvyhhLjy1dhzmFDemC7DM47cYPKWJs1WAp51t40D7Wwafhoo5/wu7i4aP/T2zkE@NgEuM004UaIrqOtD6As3ielJ2v7ESXxOp55ndeudzrft7J3v2koVVFEilz8kQ1ObLRVlyNQDXLu63ftX5aIBXk2W6HrIvDzzH2dlnDnxy5N3rVGwyknA8v)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 145 bytes

Naive solution

```c
int main(void) {
	putchar("3217411852982168523854859970943522338543662062483734873123759256062284894717957712649730999336795919"[getchar()]);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc09CsJAEEDh2j1FSJUUws7/DFaeQyzCKprCGCTaiGdfI1YPvuaV7VJKrWmcluY2jFP3uo@nvnmnzfxcynV4dC0hGAO4YDiCriUXdomwHEyCSD8gVcyK7GTEbgRIJoGiK6KzBxtYiBmgchjliCDSlQKiPVzO/11/7Hfpk2rdfwE)

Comment: [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fcg7CsJAFAXQvaRKECHv/y6p7N1EGPykMEiYTlz7OFYHTjnXUlp7rds@Tp/3se31Pl4HYQolSmMkk3clTdOAmKFizPIPcefZWVNCNEOIJQxs3pNTExoUsAhiV4TMAES8FwjD6XGr5bke4zQt39YuPw "C (tcc) – Try It Online")