# Calculate the sum of all odd digits of pi in range

Tags: code-golf, integer, pi

## Introduction

In the not so distant future with the AI revolution, we will need a way to solve their captchas to prove we're not humans.

This challenge was inspired by [CommitStrip](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/07/06/meanwhile-in-a-parallel-universe/).

## Challenge

One such captcha is the challenge of calculating the sum of all odd digits of Pi from digit 1 to digit n, including the first digit, being 3.

#### Output

- The **calculated sum** of all odd digits in the range 1 to n.

## Rules

- All the digits of pi must be calculated by your program at runtime, how you implement that is up to you.
- Hard-coded constants of pi are not allowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest bytes win.

## Example

If n = 6, we must find the sum of the odd digits in `[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]` meaning an output of `19`

## Other

Since this questions keeps getting marked as a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84444/find-the-nth-decimal-of-pi), allow me to explain how this is different.

This question asks for the sum of a range of numbers, not finding the nth decimal.

Comment: Does the range include the first 3? Does the count start at that three (is it the first element or is it seperate from the count, i.e, the zeroth element)?

Comment: @Mackan90096 Even though you've specified the output "Must be Calculated", this requirement is Non-observable, meaning it's difficult and case-by-case to determine if an answer is valid. It would be easier to define your challenge in such as way that hard-coding the answer isn't a good tactic, like having variable input.

Comment: Edited to make more sense by making the range 1 to n, @ATaco

Comment: If n = 6, we must find the sum of the odd digits in {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9}, so 19? If this is what you mean, then in the case n=31,415 the sum equals 78,664, not 78,659 as you stated in the example. Please clarify.

Comment: Also, I meant the three at the start, the first digit, not the first three digits like you wrote.

Comment: My mistake, I've gone ahead and fixed it, @sagiksp, and yes, including the first digit.

Comment: _All the digits of pi must be calculated by your program_: does that mean no hardcoding of the first N digits of PI or no built-in at all? (Edit: apparently, this rule comes from the initial version of the challenge, where the number of digits was fixed to 31415. Now that the length is taken as input, it should probably be removed.)

Comment: How about `žs` in 05AB1E? Since the digits are technically [hardcoded in the language source code](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/lib/constants.py), does that mean it's not allowed?

Comment: "All the digits of pi must be calculated by your program" is a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/10002#10002), so I'd recommend removing it.

Comment: The title is misleading. The sum of all digits of pi is infinity

Comment: The question suffers from unclear working. I think the author meant to imply no built-ins for `π`, i.e. you have to code the algorithm yourself. If this is the case, the [question indicated as a duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84444/find-the-nth-decimal-of-pi) is actually different, because built-ins are allowed in that question.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way this challenge can be done is by computing all digits of π up to n'th digit. Also as far as I know, all the existing algorithms to compute π at n'th digit in decimal also compute π at all digits before position n. Therefore programs in the other challenge can be trivially ported into this one. I agree that it's a duplicate.

Comment: **[This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8286/69850) is the guideline to close as duplicate**. In my opinion, computing π is much harder than filter out odd digits and take the sum, so (2) is true. (1) and (3) is obviously true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

As you can see [here](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Xz@/oEQ/o7Q4W98DSCjolioonVucpmr0qG3ikQ3nG5QUzBTs9FNSy/TzSnNyFIzs1Ay5uJITSxT08ktL9DKK//8HAA)<sup>1</sup> the following program, does indeed compute all the digits itself:

```
Σf%2↑İπ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziNFWjR20Tj2w43/D//38zAA)

#### Explanation

```
Σf%2↑İπ  -- implicit input N, eg: 8
     İπ  -- compute all digits of pi: [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,...
    ↑    -- take N: [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6]
 f%2     -- filter out even ones: [3,1,1,5,9]
Σ        -- sum: 19
```

<sup>1: This is a link to the Haskell code which is generated by Husk, in case you're lost (it's quite long) just search for `func_intseq 'π'`..</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/), 346 bytes

Based on a recursive implementation of the [Chudnovsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm), one of the fastest algorithms to estimate pi. For each iteration, roughly 14 digits are estimated (take a look [here](https://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky/) for further details).

```
def f(n):import decimal as d;d.getcontext().prec=n+10;q=lambda n,k=6,m=1,l=13591409,x=1,i=1:(d.Decimal(((k**3-16*k)*m//i**3)*(l+545140134))/(x*-262537412640768000)+q(n,k+12,(k**3-16*k)*m//i**3,l+545140134,x*-262537412640768000,i+1)if i<n else 13591409);return sum([ord(i)%2 and int(i)for i in str(426880*d.Decimal(10005).sqrt()/q(n//14+1))[:n+1]])
```

Ungolfed version

```
def f(n):
    import decimal as d
    d.getcontext().prec = n + 10
    q=lambda n, k=6, m=1, l=13591409, x=1, i=1:\
        (d.Decimal(((k ** 3 - 16 * k) * m // i**3) * (l + 545140134)) / (x * -262537412640768000) +
         q(n, k+12, (k ** 3 - 16 * k) * m // i**3, l + 545140134, x * -262537412640768000, i+1)if i < n else 13591409)
    return sum([ord(i) % 2 and int(i)for i in
                str(426880 * d.Decimal(10005).sqrt() / q(n // 14+1))[:n + 1]])
```

Function `q` computes the value of `S`(see the reference), than it is used to divide the term `426880 * d.Decimal(10005).sqrt()` and get the value of the approximation of pi. 
The precision is controlled by setting the value of `d.getcontext().prec`.

A a little bit longer (372 bytes), more golfed but all-in-one version:

```
f=lambda n,k=6,m=1,l=13591409,x=1,i=0:not i and(exec('global d;import decimal as d;d.getcontext().prec=%d+10'%n)or sum([ord(i)%2 and int(i)for i in str(426880*d.Decimal(10005).sqrt()/f(n//14+1,k,m,l,x,1))[:n+1]]))or i<n and d.Decimal(((k**3-16*k)*m//i**3)*(l+545140134))/(x*-262537412640768000)+f(n,k+12,(k**3-16*k)*m//i**3,l+545140134,x*-262537412640768000,i+1)or 13591409
```

Thanks to [O.O.Balance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79343/o-o-balance) to push me to go deeper into this challenge: it was very fun and interesting.

### Old answer, based on `math.pi` (74 bytes)

```
import math;f=lambda n:sum([ord(i)%2and int(i)for i in"%.*G"%(n,math.pi)])
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/MintyReasonableLoaderprogram)

N.B.: `math.pi` is ["The mathematical constant π = 3.141592…, to available precision."](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html), but the digits for the challenge are computed on the fly through the rounding and truncating operations. So, technically this is not a violation of the rules: *"all the digits of pi must be calculated by your program at runtime."*

Comment: The problem with your answer is that the maximum `n` it supports is way too small. https://repl.it/repls/WittyPoliteBug

Comment: @O.O.Balance I think I've fixed the problem. Thanks for the review.

Comment: Looks good now :-)

Comment: There's some great work here. Please vote for the question to be reopened.

Comment: @YiminRong [This can be trivially ported to the other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168195/69850).

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 53 bytes

```
Total@DeleteCases[(RealDigits@N[Pi,#])[[1]],_?EvenQ]&
```

Mathematica noob, please excuse me.

Comment: I don‘t think that should count as "calculating all the digits of pi by your program".

Comment: It is frequently done in other pi-related challeanges, I don't see the problem.. Mathematica is generating pi to the number of digits requested, I believe the poster meant to not use any hardcoded constants.

Comment: That's what I meant, @sagiksp, updated the post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 78 bytes

```rb
f=->n{"#{eval'x=2*10**n+p*x/=2+p+p-=1;'*x=p=4*n}"[0,n].bytes.sum{|c|c%2*c%16}}
```

Computes only to necessary precision.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcPRCoMgFADQX5FGBFdzKlsvw/2I@FBST@simcNQv93twDnicrW26fGNubvl9Tt/hqQVSAGA1EO6a0U99aOWrwGS9voBWDsjGFq@XOcaeIh7Lq64XoHr5VRrM5KRiRElGHn@SyEs32efCxYfz0A2g7a2Hw)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 275 bytes

```
import java.math.*;
n->{int j,t,i=0,s=3;for(;i<n-1;++i){var a=BigInteger.TEN.pow(10010).multiply(new BigInteger("2"));var p=a;for(j=1;a.signum()>0;p=p.add(a))a=a.multiply(new BigInteger(j+"")).divide(new BigInteger((2*j+++1)+""));s+=((t=(p+"").charAt(i+1)-48)%2)*t;}return s;}
```

Uses the approach from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97365) answer by [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) to calculate the digits. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##dZHBitswEIbvfoohUJDiRGunPbRotdBCDzlsG9jeSg@zseLItWUhjb0Nwc@eSk5KS2HnMNKMfn2MfjU44rqpfl5M53pP0MRadEhHsZTZ3R2UH0D/Io/wfCId4NB7oKOGqzpzw3Nr9rBvMQR4RGPhnEEMY0n7A@417G6dWxccS9lyOXenOd8ogZDiMvamgi6y2BN5Y@vvPwB9Hfg/oB04Awoudv1wTrhmRSujilVQb2WckElzb9elzHPDzyN6QPXJ1Ns4U629@Pb5i3D9CyuLoiy46IaWjGtPzOoX@Ctji82Cc5luO4UztVGlRBFMbYeO8YdCOuUEVhVDzlHhq6QmX0SUqMxoKv3/IdssmzzPSz6LZMgVY6SYS6XYH9F/JGbi8frde/5mw5ckJ69p8BaCnC5/DAGZZVe3YLeNzlz3YsR20F8P7DH95257M32Op1Mg3Yl@IOGillrLZkF6aLI0@VvIuNxHomi1renIOERXIdmavQZxRrh54Mi6iqZsuvwG).

Answer (score 0):

## SmallTalk – 299 bytes

Relies on the identity `tan⁻¹(x) = x − x³/3 + x⁵/5 − x⁷/7 ...`, and that `π = 16⋅tan⁻¹(1/5) − 4⋅tan⁻¹(1/239)`, so no “cheats”.

```
|l a b c d e f g h p t s|l:=stdin nextLine asInteger. a:=1/5. b:=1/239. c:=a. d:=b. e:=a. f:=b. g:=3. h:=-1. s:=0. l timesRepeat:[c:=c*a*a. d:=d*b*b. e:=h*c/g+e. f:=h*d/g+f. g:=g+2. h:=0-h]. p:=4*e-f*4. l timesRepeat:[t:=p floor. p:=(p-t)*10. t odd ifTrue:[s:=s+t]]. Transcript show:s printString;cr
```

Save as `pi.st`. You provide the number of digits from the console when you run it, or through the `<<<` operator.

```
$ gst -q pi.st <<< 6
19
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 119 bytes

```
y=sum([int(i)for i in str(sum([4/j if j%4%3 else-4/j for j in range(10**8)if j%2]))[0:n+1].replace('.','')if int(i)%2])
```

My first code-golf submit, so please be gentle ._.

This computes pi on the fly using the Gregory-Leibniz series. X may prove insufficient for big n, but be aware of the RAMifications of choosing a large x.

### Explanation:

#### Computation of Pi:

i.e.
`sum( [4/i if i%4==1 else -4/i for i in range(x) if i%2==1] )`
with x as large as sensible, also `i%4==1` is one byte larger than `i%4%3`, so that's nice...

#### Casting **a lot** and eventual sum:

I'm sure there are better possibilities than all this, but I cast the float to string, take the first n*1 chars (including the dec point), replace the point, then cast each char in my string to int for the modulo check at the very end of the code, and take the sum of all i that are odd to assign them to y.

#### Room for improvement:

I'm sure there's lots, but I am the least happy with the series to compute pi, and also with the multiple int() casts ad the need to replace the dec point...
*HELP*

Comment: `import math
y=sum([int(i) for i in str(math.atan(1)*4)[0:n+1].replace('.','') if int(i)%2])` is 91 bytes and calculates pi using math.atan - probably well within the requirements of calculating pi on the fly, and the issue of lacking precision is gone i guess. if this is indeed legal calculation of pi in this task, i will replace it.

Comment: Any solution based on floating points will be wrong after about the 17th digit.

Comment: both `math.pi` and `math.atan` seem to manage 48 digits after the decimal point...same if it is casted to `float`. _Instead of displaying the full decimal value, many languages (including older versions of Python), round the result to 17 significant digits_ - found that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html),so maybe your reply is for python 2?

Comment: Sure, you can print out `math.pi` to an arbitrarily large amount of digits, but (after a point) those digits are incorrect! They are not the digits of pi.

Comment: `print('{:10.100f}'.format(math.pi))` yields
`3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, and for the non-zero digits, they are true to the value of pi if one looks them up. what other method would you recommend to use? if one computes them with a series (as my answer does) they will also be inaccurate after some number of digits, as is the nature of pi calculation as i understand it. if you suggest a more efficient series i am glad to consider it.

Comment: No they aren't. π ≃ 3.141592653589793**23846**.

Comment: Of course you can't compute it to infinite precision, but you must compute it to `n` digits of accuracy.