# Pi Hunting - find an index of Pi whose value matches its index

Tags: code-golf

Given π to an arbitrary number of places, your challenge is to locate indices of π where the index (1,2,3,4...) and the string of numbers from that index carry the same value for the length of the index.

That sounds complex, so let's look at an example!

Indices will count from +1 upwards through natural whole integers, skipping 0 as the first index:

1, 2, 3, 4,.... up to an arbitrary whole positive number.

If the number being used (instead of π) was:

`123456789101112`

then for each index value 1... the sequence of numbers at that index position would match with the value of the index.

At position `1` the string '1' can be found

```
123456789101112
^
```

At position `2` the string '2' can be found

```
123456789101112
 ^
```

If this sequence continue to 10, you'd find that at position `10` the sequence '10' is found.

```
123456789101112
         ^
```

However, when you reach position `11`, you find '01', not '11'.

```
123456789101112
          ^
```

Given an input value of π of the format:

`3.14159...`

and taking off `3.` to give `14159...` using indices start at 1, so the first string found at index 1 is "1", the first string found at index 2 is "4", etc.

Find the shortest code to locate the first 4 indices where the set of characters at that index position have the same numerical sequence as the numbers that make up the index.

Shortest wins!

Built-ins are allowed

Examples of finding the nth digit of pi:

[Find the nth decimal of pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84444/find-the-nth-decimal-of-pi)

The major step here is to make the comparison of the nth digit and 'n' to determine if there's a match.

** First Match **

3.14159265

1 : finds '1'

A simple psuedo-code approach might be similar to the following, except this one doesn't account for "3." or the index being off by 1:

`assume input=pi to any arbitrary length supported with '3.' removed`

```
for(var index=0, maximumInputLength=input.length; index < maxmimumInputLength; index++) {
 var indexString = '' + i;
 var indexLength = indexString.length;
 if(indexString.substr(index, indexLength) == indexString) {
    // index found at index'th position
 } else {
    // index not found at index'th position
 }
}
```

This style of solution will return '6' found in the 6th index position and '27' found in the 27th index position.

Given 141 592 6 (6 is in the 7th position starting at 0).

To verify if an answer is correct, you can use the above code to find the nth digit of pi and compare to the value of 'n' in your language of choice!

**Thank you for the great feedback in helping me write a better first question.**

**Clarifications:**

- Is π given as an input - YES

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65032/discussion-on-question-by-mystream-pi-hunting-find-an-index-of-pi-whose-value).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 64 bytes

```python
i=1
while i<len(P):
	if int(P[i:i+len(str(i))])==i:print i
	i+=1
```

As you said, pi's digits are given, so I chose the variable `P` to contain the entire digit string.
The full code first downloads [one billion digits of pi](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/pi/pi-billion.txt) to a file using cURL and then reads in that file to process it.

```python
"Setting up pi's digits."; exec'import os\nN,f=200000000,"pi.txt"\nif not os.path.exists(f):os.system("curl https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/pi/pi-billion.txt>"+f)\nP=open(f,"r").read()[1:N+2][:-1]'
"Search through pi.";      exec'i=1\nwhile i<len(P):\n\tif int(P[i:i+len(str(i))])==i:print i\n\ti+=1'
```

Though, when one knows the answer, a simple plaintext output is actually shorter (29 bytes).

```python
print"1,16470,44899,79873884"
```

This series of numbers is also known to the OEIS (http://oeis.org/A057680).

Comment: Isn't your second solution one of the forbidden standard loopholes?

Comment: does i++ work in python? to save a character?

Comment: @DirtyDev Well, the question says _Given π_ and _assume input=pi to any arbitrary length supported with '3.' removed_, so I let `P` equal pi in my program.
However, with `P` not declared, the code snippet does not work and thus I provided a fully functional program that downloads a file containing pi and assigns it to `P`. After that my provided code snippet is executed.

Comment: @MyStream No, it does not. Python has the Negation (Arithmetic) and Positive operators defined as `-` and `+`. Thus the expressions `--3 == 3` and `+++68 == 68` are true. `i=0;i++` even raises an error, as there is no `++` operator. More about Python operators [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

Comment: @JonathanFrech no that part is totally fine, I meant the print"..." thing

Comment: @DirtyDev Yes, indeed the loopholes forbid a plaintext output (https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/73111), yet this loophole's comments also suggest that a plaintext output should not be possible. I just wanted to mention the possibility of a plaintext output which unfortunately requires less bytes.