# Encrypt a string using vigenere techniques

Tags: code-golf, cipher

Your task:

Create a program that encrypts a string with another string using a key, using 
the vigenere cipher.

What a vigenere cipher does

```
Ciphertext:   string  
Key:          keya   
 |             |
 v             v
string
keyake
 |
 v
(18)(19)(17)(08)(13)(06)
(10)(04)(24)(00)(10)(04)
 |
 v
(28)(23)(41)(08)(23)(10)
 |
 v
cxpixk
```

If it still isn't clear, read [here.](http://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher)

Rules: No built-ins, shortest code in bytes wins, input and output will/should always be either completely lowercase, or completely uppercase.

```
string, keya -> cxpixk
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
vigenere, cipher -> xqvlrvtm
short, longkey -> dvbxd
```

Comment: [Similar, possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/678/20260)

Comment: This challenge could really benefit from a description of the cipher.

Comment: If the key is longer than the text, should we lengthen the text? You do it in your second testcase, but not in the fourth testcase

Comment: Your plaintext of **a**'s is two letters shorter than its ciphertext.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

2 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```
ṁ⁹,OS‘ịØA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4bmB4oG5LE9T4oCY4buLw5hB////S0VZQf9TVFJJTkc)

### How it works

```
ṁ⁹,OS‘ịØA            arguments: "KEYA", "STRING"

ṁ⁹         reshape   "KEYAKE"
  ,        pair      ["KEYAKE","STRING"]
   O       codepoint [[75,69,89,65,75,69],[83,84,82,73,78,71]]
    S      sum       [158,153,171,138,153,140]
     ‘     add 1     [159,154,172,139,154,141]
      ịØA  index ØA  "CXPIXK"
           where ØA is "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPSRQTUVWXYZ"
```

Comment: Uppercase letters would save two bytes.

Comment: @Dennis nice observation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
ạᵐz{+-₁₂%₂₆;Ạ∋₍}ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuhQ@3Tqiq1tZ91NT4qKlJFYgfNbVZP9y14FFH96Om3lqgdPL//9FK2amViUo6SsUlRZl56Uqx/6MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 114 bytes

```r
l=letters
i=match
s=strsplit
function(m,k)cat(l[(i(s(m,'')[[1]],l)+i(s(k,'')[[1]],l)-2)%%26+1][1:nchar(m)],sep='')
```

Returns a function that takes the message and the key and prints the result to stdout. Will explain later (on mobile now)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xDsMgDEV37hEZFDokQ4dKnIQyIEQSFEMicIeenpqtm/3et3/tHQ1GolibSCZ7CodoplFtNyYSm9k@JVC6isz6VMGTRCuTbLwCKGsX5zSqeZDznzxWNU3rc16cXV4lHL7KrJxu8Tac6psE7khlBw1n/HpQYvyGd@FpyOOqxA6vsrPnix8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
s.e@GsxLG,@QkbE
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.e%40GsxLG%2C%40QkbE&input=%22keya%22%0A%22string%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>75</s> 73 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun*

```python
f=lambda a,b:a and chr((ord(a[0])+ord(b[0])+1)%26+64)+f(a[1:],b[1:]+b[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5BbsMgELz7FSukSiCjqkmrHCzlJRYHsBdD4wABksb5vAOOcuwcRrszs9oJSzbefa@rPs7yrEYJkquusBthMJFSH0cq@y/B2jqpbdqxj/2hPfywVhdv1wmuKrebu2ZMOcER@p6kHK2bCCcnXCQRHHoi/0EJSTWMqCdjf0/z2flwiSlfb3/35fE6vdkJHUYkHMhgg8H40pPxMVdx9m4qn4gQTaN9hIz3zKEoYB1stboGKkKplammNfB5DQEjZVvwvTC2PgE)

Takes input in uppercase

Comment: You don't need to minus 194. You just need to minus 12 for lowercase, and add 1 for uppercase, so using uppercase would be shorter.

Comment: `(ord(a[0])+ord(b[0])+1)%26+64` won't work for **Z**. `(ord(a[0])+ord(b[0]))%26+65` should (and saves two bytes).